# Unable to get a factorial function to work in C

Tags: c, factorial

I cannot get the following code to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// I am not sure whethere I should void here or not.
int main() {
    // when the first bug is solved, I put here arg[0]. It should be
    // similar command line parameter as args[0] in Java.
    int a=3;                  
    int b; 
    b = factorial(a);

    // bug seems to be here, since the %1i seems to work only in fprintf
    printf("%1i", b);
    return 0;      
}  

int factorial(int x) {
    int i; 
    for(i=1; i<x; i++) 
        x *= i; 
    return x; 
}
```

**How can you get the code to work?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AInitak gave the right answer, but I want to add that one way you can *find* the bug in your code is to print out the values of `i` and `x` in the factorial loop.

```
int factorial(int x) {
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<x; i++)
    {
        x *= i;
        printf("%d, %d\n", i, x);
    }
    return x;
}
```

This gives you the output

```
1, 3
2, 6
3, 18
4, 72
5, 360
6, 2160
7, 15120
8, 120960
9, 1088640
10, 10886400
11, 119750400
12, 1437004800
13, 1501193216
14, -458131456
-458131456
```

This makes it easier to see what's going wrong.  The loop doesn't stop where you expect it to for the reasons AInitak explained.

Answer (score 15):

You're modifying your loop terminating variable (x) inside the loop.  Currently your code blows up after a few iterations, when *x* overflows the range of a 32 bit integer and then becomes negative and very large, hence terminating the loop.

It should be:

```
int factorial(int n) {
    int i, x = 1;
    for (i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        x *= i;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Better yet, you should use `long` instead of `int` for the variable `x` and the return value, because *n!* gets very large very quickly.

Comment: I changed ints to longs. I get the following error message: http://dpaste.com/42442/ . I apparently need to have some library.

Comment: you changed too many ints.  The return from main should still be an int.

Answer (score 3):

It's bad style in C to leave out `void` when defining or declaring a function. So put it in

```
int main(void)
```

While it doesn't change anything about the number of parameters the function has (the function has zero parameters without that `void` either), it will declare the function as one that accepts only zero arguments, while it won't tell anything about the amount and types of accepted arguments when you omit the `void`. However, both versions with and without `void` are correct.

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/c-void-arguments/693883#693883) about that matter too.

Comment: @litb: It seems that C is like Python. Let's assume than I use the convention "Explicit is better than implicit". Am I better of with it in C than without it?

Comment: Yes, i think that rule generally is fine. There are cases where i would use implicit things: Like converting from void* to something else, if the result is the same anyway, or conversion from int to long (but not the other way around). In this particular case however, missing void will have a different result (won't give the function a prototype - so neither arguments can be type-checked nor it's known how many arguments are expected). So in this case, always go with "void".

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int c,char *v[])

{

    int x,y;

    int *num;

    if(c==1)

    {

    printf("Usage : programName : number");

    return 0;

    }

    num=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

    *num=atoi(v[1]);

    x=1;y=1;

    while(x<=*num)

    {

    y=y*x;

    x++;

    }

    printf("Factorial of %d is %d ",*num,y);

    free(num);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: output: factorial : 5                                                                         factorial of 5 is 120

Answer (score 1):

What error message do you get?

First off, declare your function `factorial` *before* `main`. Also, pay attention to correct indentation. Your declaration of function `main` is correct, by the way.

Comment: Not in C; it should have a "void". See litb's answer.

Comment: @Thank you for pointing the convention out which I did not follow. My error "message" was that I got a too large negative number.

Comment: What should I correct in my indentation to get it more C-like?

Comment: @Steve: I somewhat disagree: you shouldn't call `main` manually anyway. It's bad style.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use also double or unsigned long for factorial computation in order to be able to compute the greater value of the factorial function.

```
double fact( double n)
{
   if ( n == 1)
        return 1;
   return n*(fact(n-1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant non-recursive function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
long long int fact(long long int);

long long int fact(long long int n){
    long long int num = 1;
    long long int fi = 0;
    for(long long int i=2;i<=n;i++){
        for(long long int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            fi += num;      
        }
        num = fi;
        fi = 0;
    }       
return num;
}    
int main(){
    long long int n;
    scanf("%lld",&n);
    printf("%lld\n",fact(n));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you compare your proposal to BillTheLizard's one, please. http://stackoverflow.com/a/843221/54964 So why is your proposal better than his? What is the purpose of `long long int`?