# Functions of structures in C

Tags: c, struct, declaration, typedef, function-declaration

I am learning linked lists in C , and I don't understand these 2 lines:

```
struct LinkedList{
    int data;
    struct LinkedList *next;
 };

typedef struct LinkedList *node; //1

node createNode(){               //2
    node temp; 
    temp = (node)malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedList)); 
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

In //1 What does it mean to assign a pointer as a name for the structure in typedef?
and in //2 how can we have a function of the structure(node aka struct Linkedlist) ,as functions cannot be members of structures?

Comment: `//1` is just like any other typedef. It creates a short name for a type, in this case `node` is equivalent to `struct LinkedList *`

Comment: That's not a member of structure. It's a function that returns a `node`.

Comment: Side notes: [do not cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2505965), and [avoid empty parameter lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803937/func-vs-funcvoid-in-c99).

Comment: See [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750178/15168) — TL;DR, the answer is generally "No", with possible exceptions for function pointer types.

Answer (score 3):

1. A typedef is like an alias. You're saying that `node` is `struct LinkedList *` (A pointer to an struct). You can then use `node` like you would use any type.
2. That `node` is just the return value of the function. That function returns a new `node`

Answer (score 1):

This typedef declaration

```
typedef struct LinkedList *node;
```

introduces the type specifier `node` as an alias for the pointer type `struct LinkedList *`. So instead of writing

```
struct LinkedList * temp;
```

you my just write

```
node temp;
```

As for the function createNode

```
node createNode(){               //2
    node temp; 
    temp = (node)malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedList)); 
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

then it is a standalone function. It is not a member of the structure. The function has the return type `struct LinkedList *` that is written by using its alias `node`.

Comment: Thanks so much , that makes sense to me now.