# Implicit Declaration of Function in C on CodeBlocks

Tags: c, codeblocks, implicit-declaration

Hello I am practicing my knowledge in C language I am trying to make a simple calculator but I encountered this warning `Implicit Declaration of Function` but the function that I called has been executed. I tried to fix it with this `void start();` but the function did not execute.

Successful executed the function `start();` but have a implicit warning:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void addition()
{
    int vala, valb, resu;
    system("cls");
    printf("SiMPLE CALCULATOR 1.0a\n");
    printf("ADDITION\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter the first value of addend: ");
    scanf("%d", &vala);
    printf("Enter the second value of addend: ");
    scanf("%d", &valb);
    resu=vala+valb;
    printf("The sum of %d and %d is: %d\n", vala, valb, resu);
    printf("PRESS [ANY KEY] TO CONTINUE...");
    getch();

    start(); \\THIS CODE
}

void start()
{
    char ope;
    system("cls");
    printf("SiMPLE CALCULATOR 1.0a\n");
    printf("What operation will be used:");
    scanf("%s", &ope);

    if (ope == 'a')
    {
        addition();
    }
    else if (ope == 'b')
    {
        printf("bbbbbbbbbbbb\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ccccccccccc\n");
    }

}

int main()
{
    int choices;
    printf("SiMPLE CALCULATOR 1.0a\n");
    printf("choose an option:");
    scanf("%d", &choices);

    if (choices == 1)
    {
        start();
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Failed to execute the function `void start();` start but no implicit warning:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void addition()
{
    int vala, valb, resu;
    system("cls");
    printf("SiMPLE CALCULATOR 1.0a\n");
    printf("ADDITION\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter the first value of addend: ");
    scanf("%d", &vala);
    printf("Enter the second value of addend: ");
    scanf("%d", &valb);
    resu=vala+valb;
    printf("The sum of %d and %d is: %d\n", vala, valb, resu);
    printf("PRESS [ANY KEY] TO CONTINUE...");
    getch();

    void start(); \\THIS CODE
}

void start()
{
    char ope;
    system("cls");
    printf("SiMPLE CALCULATOR 1.0a\n");
    printf("What operation will be used:");
    scanf("%s", &ope);

    if (ope == 'a')
    {
        addition();
    }
    else if (ope == 'b')
    {
        printf("bbbbbbbbbbbb\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ccccccccccc\n");
    }

}

int main()
{
    int choices;
    printf("SiMPLE CALCULATOR 1.0a\n");
    printf("choose an option:");
    scanf("%d", &choices);

    if (choices == 1)
    {
        start();
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put `void start();` at the beginning of the program, before the `addition` function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [warning: implicit declaration of function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440816/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function)

Comment: `void start();` within a function simply declares that somewhere in the program there is a function called `start`.  It does not actually call that function; that still would have to be done with just `start();`

Comment: Note that in C, the proper way to declare a function taking no arguments is not `void start();` but `void start(void);`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803937/func-vs-funcvoid-in-c99.  C++ is different, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032/is-there-a-difference-between-foovoid-and-foo-in-c-or-c/51080#51080.

Comment: Unrelated, but `char ope; scanf("%s", &ope);` is a serious bug.  It reads a string of unlimited length into a space only large enough for one character, resulting in writing out of bounds and undefined behavior.  Code like this is how people get hacked.

Comment: @NateEldredge im gonna change it later with %c thanks for saying that.

Comment: @NateEldredge ,ohh im gonna try that `void start(void);` thanks

Comment: @NateEldredge it worked `void start(void);` thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start()` is declare after `addition()`, but in `addition()` you call `start()`, so the compiler don't know what `start()` is. Also, in `start()` you also call `addition()`, so the best way to reslove this is using forward declaration:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void start(void); /* forward declaration */
void addition(void); /* forward declaration */

void addition(void)
{
    int vala, valb, resu;
    system("cls");
    printf("SiMPLE CALCULATOR 1.0a\n");
    printf("ADDITION\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter the first value of addend: ");
    scanf("%d", &vala);
    printf("Enter the second value of addend: ");
    scanf("%d", &valb);
    resu=vala+valb;
    printf("The sum of %d and %d is: %d\n", vala, valb, resu);
    printf("PRESS [ANY KEY] TO CONTINUE...");
    getch();

    start(); 
}

void start(void)
{
    char ope;
    system("cls");
    printf("SiMPLE CALCULATOR 1.0a\n");
    printf("What operation will be used:");
    scanf("%s", &ope);

    if (ope == 'a')
    {
        addition();
    }
    else if (ope == 'b')
    {
        printf("bbbbbbbbbbbb\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ccccccccccc\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: doing that will make more warnings a total of 8 warnings. 4 warnings with implicit to my addition, subtraction, multiplication and division functions. and 4 warnings saying that conflicting types for my addition, subtraction, multiplication and division functions.

Comment: @Pyromagne What warning, exactly?

Comment: 4 warnings with implicit to my addition, subtraction, multiplication and division functions. and 4 warnings saying that conflicting types for my addition, subtraction, multiplication and division functions.

Comment: @Pyromagne those waring doesn't related to the changes, but rather something in your code that you haven't show us (I think)

Comment: ohhh yeah I didnt realized it but I finished it with warnings but in the version I submited theres a total of 2 warning implicit for addition and conflicting type for addition. sorry

Comment: Hi thanks for taking time with my question, I change `void start();` to `void start(void);` and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not advisable to take measures which allow you to call `start` from `addition`, leading to a potentially infinite recursion, only to fake a loop. Better drop the `start();` call in `addition` and replace the `scanf("%s", &ope);` with `while (scanf(" %c", &ope) > 0)`.

Comment: My plan is after printing the result  I want the program go back to `start` to make another calculation how can I do that if I am going to remove `start();`?

Comment: You can do that exactly as I wrote; if you don't believe it, you can try. (The function `addition` automatically returns to where it was called.)