# Segmentation Fault linear search algorithm

Tags: c, search, segmentation-fault, fault, linear-search

This algorithm is a linear search algorithm that finds the desired value. But when I compile this code, gives the segmentation fault in if(dizi[i]==aranan) this line. How can I solve this ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int N,i,aranan;

int ArrayBastir(int *dizi,int N)
{
    printf("My numbers\n");
    for(int i =0; i<N;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", dizi[i]);
    }
}
int findValue()
{

    printf("The value you want to search");
    scanf("%d",&aranan);

}
int Output(int *dizi,int N,int aranan)
{

    for(int i =0; i<N;i++)
    {
        if(dizi[i]==aranan)
        {
            printf("%d number %d. found in queue \n", aranan,i+1);
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    int N;
    int aranan;
    printf("Please enter how many numbers you want to enter");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int dizi[N];

    for(int i =0; i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &dizi[i]);
    }

    ArrayBastir(   dizi, N);
    findValue(aranan);
    Output(*dizi,N,aranan);
    return 1;
}
```

Linear Search algorithm

Comment: Compilation cannot end with a segmentation fault (unless there's a bug in the compiler itself).

Comment: And you should call `Output(dizi,N,aranan)`, not `Output(*dizi,N,aranan)`.

Comment: Why ? It doesn't give  any output

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings. You pass incorrect types to your function.  The compiler should tell you. For GCC ot clang use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: Thanks ı changed to Output(dizi,N,aranan) but the same

Comment: Remove your 3 global variables. You are not using two of them and the thirs is used incorrectly.

Comment: General note: You should always check return value of `scanf` to see if input was valid. Otherwise you might work with uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two objects defined as:

```
int aranan;
```

Once is defined at file scope (a global), and one is defined within the scope of `main`.

When `findValue(aranan)` is called, a copy of the [uninitialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) value of `aranan` within the scope of `main` is passed to `findValue`. `findValue` is [lacking a prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41803937/2505965), having not declared its arguments, so this is ignored.

`findValue` scans a value into the file scope `aranan`, but when `Output(*dizi, N, aranan)` is called it uses the value of `aranan` defined within `main`. `aranan` within `main` was never initialized, and thus this causes `Output` to search for an [indeterminate value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

Additionally, `*dizi` is an `int`, when `Output` expects an `int *` as its first argument.

`ArrayBastir` and `Output` are also defined as each returning an `int`, which they do not do.

You should not ignore the return value of [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), as it indicates the number of *successful conversions*, or a negative value on failure (`EOF`). In a program this small, you can get away with writing a simple wrapper function for reading integers, that just exits the program if the user enters something invalid.

`main` returning nonzero generally indicates your program failed. `main` is special - it is the only non-void function where you can omit a return statement. If `main` reaches the end of execution without an explicit `return`, it is treated as though it returned `0`.

---

The issues above can be mitigated by avoiding the use of *global* variables, and by turning up your compilers warning level to catch obvious type mismatches.

For [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html), use `-Wall -Wextra`, and possibly `-Werror`.

For [MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=msvc-170), use `/Wall`, and possibly `/Wx`.

Minimally refactored:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_int(void)
{
    int x;

    if (1 != scanf("%d", &x)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return x;
}

void ArrayBastir(int *dizi, int N)
{
    printf("My numbers\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", dizi[i]);
    }
}

void Output(int *dizi, int N, int aranan)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (dizi[i] == aranan) {
            printf("Found <%d> at position %d.\n", aranan, i);
        }
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    printf("Please enter how many numbers you want to enter: ");
    int N = get_int();
    int dizi[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        dizi[i] = get_int();
    }

    ArrayBastir(dizi, N);

    printf("Enter the value you want to search for: ");
    int aranan = get_int();

    Output(dizi, N, aranan);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate for your effort and taking time. I really like the control expression when the value is retrieved from the user with scanf. I will try to use it from now on. I don't know how to use stderr I'll take a look at it. Thank you very much again for your answer, full of good tips.I want to analyze this code with Big -O notation. Do you know if there are any ready-made programs for this?

Comment: `stderr` is the appropriate stream to use for errors and diagnostics. I do not have any recommendations for programs that can analyze this code. This program is *O(n)*, however, as linear search and individually printing or populating an array are all *O(n)*.