# Why does mismatched prototype and definition with empty argument list give different results in GCC and Clang?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11

Given (simplified) code snippet:

```
void foo(int a, int b); // declaration with prototype

int main(void)
{
    foo(1, 5); // type-checked call (i.e. because of previous prototype)
    return 0;
}

void foo() // old-style definition (with empty argument list)
{

}
```

and command-line options (though, as I checked they are not important):

```
-x c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall
```

gcc 7.2 fails to compile it with following error message:

> error: number of arguments doesn't match prototype

while clang 4.0 translates it without any complaints.

Which implementation is correct according to C Standard? Is it valid that old-style definition "cancels" previous prototype?

Comment: @Grzegorz Szpetkowski You should ask yourself - what is the point of it. Why to invoke the UB?

Comment: @PeterJ_01: It may be useful to know for working with legacy code, which suprisingly compiles or not on different compilers.

Comment: @Grzegorz Szpetkowski such a code requires rewriting in the correct manner

Comment: @PeterJ_01: Code base may be large and sometimes it is not practical (in terms of business value and staff-months) to rewrite it, especially when it is already working for customers. This is especially true for mission-critical software like software for submarines or nuclear plants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<del>I do not have a quote from a standard</del> (*edit: Refer `C11`, chapter  6.7.6.3/P14*), but as per my understanding, `gcc` is right to shout, as you're contradicting yourself.

You *promised* that in the function definition, in the declaration-list, you will have two parameters of type `int`, but they are not there. In case of a function definition, and empty list means that function should take no parameter. So there is a constraint violation and `gcc` is right to complain.

It seems this is a problem in [clang](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/gcc-compatibility-error-number-of-arguments-doesn-t-match-prototype-td3834935.html) that is does not produce a warning at least.

---

Quotes:

Chapter §6.7, P4 (***Constraints***)

> All declarations in the same scope that refer to the same object or function shall specify compatible types.

then, chapter §6.7.6.3, P14,

> An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of the function. An empty
>   list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the
>   function has no parameters. The empty list in a function declarator that is not part of a
>   definition of that function specifies that no information about the number or types of the
>   parameters is supplied.

So, this constitutes a constraint violation and warrant a diagnostic to be emitted.

Comment: AFAIR it works that way in second direction, when old-style declaration prepends normal definition. For example, `int foo()` and then `int foo(int a) {}` is fine, as declaration without prototype effectively turns-off further type checking.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski Yes, but that's not the way to be used for _variadic_ notation, you know. :)

Comment: violating a *shall* is not enough to require the diagnostic, you have to precise 6.7p4 is in a constraint section

Comment: I finally marked this answer as accepted, The reason is that declarations are not compatible (as defined in 6.7.6.3/15). More specifically, the following does not hold: _"If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list, both shall agree  in  the  number  of  parameters"_. Note that `void foo() {}` does constitute a function type, that does not include a prototype, and the 6.7.6.3/15 does not require from examined function types to include such as a prototype.

Answer (score 15):

> (C11, 6.7p4 Constraints) "All declarations in the same scope that refer to the same object or function shall specify compatible types"

and

> (C11, 6.7.6.3p14) "An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of the function. An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters. [...]"

My opinion is constraint of 6.7p4 is violated and diagnostic has to be issued.

**EDIT:**

as pointed out by [@hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd) it is actually not correct. 6.7.6.3p14 does not mean `void foo() {}` provides a prototype for `foo` as per [DR#317](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_317.htm). In that sense, the 6.7p4 constraint is not violated and so clang is right not to complain.

Comment: It's well-established that `void foo()` does not provide a prototype, even in a definition. [There was a DR that answered this explicitly.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_317.htm) The type of `foo` in that definition is `void foo()`, not `void foo(void)`, and `void foo()` and `void foo(int, int)` are compatible types. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: @hvd: Except there is a declaration with prototype above `main` for `void foo(int, int)`. It is the definition of `foo` that gives an empty argument list. Doesn't this mean the prototype and definition disagree?

Comment: @jxh Yes, the prototype and the definition indeed disagree. It wouldn't surprise me if that means the code has undefined behaviour. But that's not what this answer says. This answer says the definition specifies a *type* not compatible with the earlier declaration, and because of that, a constraint is violated. The type is compatible though.

Comment: @hvd: You are a *real* language lawyer!

Comment: @hvd: Although the standard specifies an empty argument list in the function definition specifies the function has no parameters, you claim that the type of such a function is still one that can takes an unspecified number of parameters. And, you back up this claim by referencing a defect report.

Comment: @hvd I agree. I forgot this DR (even if I used it in some of my past SO answers...). I suggest you to write your own answer to this question.

Comment: @ouah Thanks, had considered it, but I was already happy with jxh's edits, will reconsider if I find something to add to that.

Comment: @hvd: Subclause 6.7.6.3/15 contains following sentence: "If one type has a _parameter type list_ and the other type is specified by a function definition that contains a _(possibly empty)_ identifier list, both shall agree in the _number of parameters_ (...)". It seems, that this is very the same case as presented in question's code snippet and this implies that both types not compatible, thus constaint is violated (as by 6.7/p4). Do you agree?

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski That's not a constraint, so a violation is undefined behaviour and a diagnostic is allowed but not required. But good find, it means clang is not wrong for accepting it *and* GCC is not wrong for rejecting it.

Comment: @hvd: But there is generic constraint in 6.7/p4, that reads "All _declarations_ in the same scope that refer to the same object or function shall specify compatible types.". Note that it does not say anything about prototype and I think it's valid to say that old-style definition is also a kind of declaration. The subclause 6.7.6.3/15 defines what function types are compatible and by my previous comment, `void foo(int a, int b);` and `void foo()` are not compatible, hence the generic constraint is violated (is it?). Where do you see flaw in my intepretation?

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski: The idea is that `void foo()` is not a prototype, it is a function declaration, *i.e.*, there is a function named `foo` that returns `void`. This is not incompatible with the prototype `void foo(int, int)`.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski What jxh said. Try `void foo(int a, int b); void foo();`. But actually, I'm getting unsure now. Although 6.7.6.3p15 has a "shall" outside of a constraint, it starts off as "For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible return types. Moreover, ..." before it gets to your "both shall agree in the number of parameters", and it could mean that it's intended to imply that although `void foo();` and `void foo() {}` both give `foo` type `void()`, only the former is compatible with `void foo(int, int);`. Making the original answer correct after all.

Comment: @jxh: The 6.7.6.3/15 requires that second type is a definition (citing: "and the other type is specified by a function definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list"). For instance, take `void foo(int, int)` and `void foo() {}`. In my opinion: 1) `void foo() {}` constitutes a function type with empty argument list 2) this type is not compatible with `void foo(int, int)` declaration because number of parameters does not agree 3) such incompability invokes constraint  6.7p4.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski: It is not clear to me that the entirety of 6.7.6.3/15  is required for compatibility. One could read only the first two sentences speaking to compatibility. The rest of the paragraph are merely more semantics. But, I am still not a language lawyer.

Answer (score 11):

<sub>Disclaimer: I am not a [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer), but I play one on [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow).</sub>

<s>If the compiler does not issue a diagnostic, it would be non-conforming, and could be considered a bug if the compiler claims to be conforming.</s>

C.2011§6.7.6.3¶14 (emphasis mine):

> An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of the function. **An empty
>   list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the
>   function has no parameters.** The empty list in a function declarator that is not part of a
>   definition of that function specifies that no information about the number or types of the
>   parameters is supplied.

Thus, the definition of `foo` specifies no parameters, while the declaration of `foo` earlier specified two parameters.

C.2011§6.7.6.3¶15:

> For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible return types.<sup>146)</sup>
>   Moreover, the parameter type lists, **if both are present**, shall agree in the number of
>   parameters and in use of the ellipsis terminator; corresponding parameters shall have
>   compatible types.
>   <sub>146) If both function types are ‘‘old style’’, parameter types are not compared.</sub>

<s>Thus, the two declarators of `foo` are not compatible.</s>
Dang! From [@hvd's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945623/why-does-mismatched-prototype-and-definition-with-empty-argument-list-give-diffe#comment78858817_45945886):

> <sup>It's well-established that `void foo()` does not provide a prototype, even in a definition. [There was a DR that answered this explicitly.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_317.htm) The type of `foo` in that definition is `void foo()`, not `void foo(void)`, and `void foo()` and `void foo(int, int)` are compatible types. This answer is incorrect.</sup>

The emphasized part of the text above from the standard is the loophole that allows for the disagreement in number of arguments, but compatible types. Although the function definition specifies a function that takes no arguments, since the parameter type list is actually missing, there is actually no incompatibility between the type of `foo` in its function prototype and the type of `foo` in the function definition.

Thus, clang 4.0 seems to have it right, since there is no constraint violation.

> <sub>My original argument becomes invalid, so editing out that part of my original answer.</sub>

---

In comments you actually presented the following example:

```
void foo () {}

int main () { foo(1, 2); return 0; }
```

And asked why the compiler does not complain for this case. This is actually addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12643202/315052), but in a nutshell: C.2011 still accepts K&R C function definition syntax. So, while `void foo() {}` is a definition that takes no arguments, the prototype that is used for argument validation is the same as `void foo();`, because the empty argument list is parsed as K&R. The modern C syntax to force proper argument checking would be to use `void foo(void) {}` instead.

Comment: C99 had the same wording (in 6.7.5.3/14).

Answer (score 7):

From the C Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))

> 15 For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify
>   compatible return types.146) Moreover, ... If one type has a parameter
>   type list and the other type is specified by a function definition
>   that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list, both shall agree in
>   the number of parameters, and the type of each prototype parameter
>   shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of
>   the default argument promotions to the type of the corresponding
>   identifier. (In the determination of type compatibility and of a
>   composite type, each parameter declared with function or array type is
>   taken as having the adjusted type and each parameter declared with
>   qualified type is taken as having the unqualified version of its
>   declared type.)

And (6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type)

> 2 All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall
>   have compatible type; otherwise, **the behavior is undefined**

Thus the shown program in the question has undefined behavior. The compiler may issue a diagnostic message as GCC did.

Comment: and some comments - this topic is live online for 15 years probably that void `foo(int) and then void foo(){...}` is correct and void foo(double)` and then void foo(){...}` is incorrect. But I am not the language lawyer

Comment: Undefined behavior does not require a diagnostic per se, so this would imply clang is correct.

Comment: @ouah: It would imply that clang is not incorrect. It would be friendlier if it issued a diagnostic.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: I'm reasonably sure that both are incorrect (undefined behavior).

Comment: @KeithThompson my point here is 6.7p4 enforces the diagnostic contrary to friendlier 6.2.7

Comment: @Keith Thompson even if both are correct I would never do it this way. The question IMO is ridiculous. It should be called: how to push myself into a difficult to debug problems

Comment: @PeterJ_01 the question is not ridiculous because if the conclusion is clang has to issue the diagnostic, it means there is a bug in clang

Comment: no it is not a bug. Compilers do not have to report UBs. But this is an example of totally silly one - and gcc is right in this case. Someone who writes function in the manner foo() {} should reconsider his approach

Comment: @PeterJ_01 but they have to report constraint violation. See my answer.

Comment: Sourav's  reference to 6.7 P4 is more specific (declarations in the same scope) and so it is that one that counts. The code has a constraint violation and so a diagnostic *must* be emitted.