# Why are there a handful of passing mentions of "function prototypes" in C++11? Surely these don't exist in C++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The C++11 standard makes a couple of passing mentions to "function prototypes".

There are not in any definitions of the relevant features, but in random places like:

- "function prototype scope" in `[C++11: 3.3.4]` (whose definition actually admits it's talking about "function declarations");
- an editorial description of the library type definition clauses in `[C++11: 17.5.1.4/1]`, footnote `175` (which seems to be referring to the C functionality);
- `[C++11: 20.9.4.3/6]` which describes the hypothetical `template <T> typename add_rvalue_reference<T>::type create();` as "a function prototype".
- the same thing at `[C++11: 20.9.6/4]`;
- appendix `[C++11: C.1.7]` which talks about declarators in C: "The function declarations using C incomplete declaration style must be completed to become full prototype declarations, then later "Rationale: Prototypes are essential to type safety".

... and *that's it*.

Surely, we are set on the "declaration"/"definition" terminology and, since the C++ standard *does not use the "prototype" terminology in its core definitions*, these are merely typos/inconsistencies, introduced because some editors are familiar with C terminology?

Or is there some subtle meaning I'm missing?

Comment: How are C prototypes "something quite different"? In C, a prototype is a function declaration that specifies the type(s) of the parameters. In C++, all function declarations do so.

Comment: @Keith: C prototypes support *identifier-list*s and all sorts of weird magic, including omitting parameters entirely (or is that declarations without prototypes?). If nothing else, the _C++_ standard calls them function declarations, so it's strange to have this small handful of passing references to different terminology.

Comment: @Lightness I think you have that [backwards](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5481685/241631). Sorry, too lazy to find something more normative than JerryCoffin :)

Comment: @Praetorian: Okay, you're right! I shall edit accordingly. It's only a small and insubstantial change to the question.

Comment: @Lightness The answer probably is *the committee members are not as anal retentive as you are* :P

Comment: @Praetorian: Something more normative: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.2.1p2: "A *function
prototype* is a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. I think some of the uses of "prototype" make sense, but others should really be changed to "declaration".

- I agree that §3.3.4/1 should talk about "function declaration scope" instead of "function prototype scope".
- §17.5.1.4 is talking about C++ headers, so I think it should probably use "declaration" instead of prototype.
- Footnote 175 is specifically referring to what is provided by C headers, so there I think it's probably appropriate to use C terminology (i.e., to continue to use "prototype", though possibly with an added note that this is equivalent to a C++ declaration).
- I'd agree that the use of "prototype" at §20.9.6/4 and §20.9.4.3/6 are both mistakes, and should use "declaration" instead.
- C.1.7 is specifically comparing C to C++, talking about declarations vs. prototypes in C and how they compare to C++ declarations, so it nearly needs to retain the use of "prototype" to be meaningful.

As to a definition of "prototype" (or related features), ISO 9899:1999 (through TC 3) is a normative reference to the C++ standard, so its definition of "prototype" can be applied since the C++ standard itself provides none.