# Algorithm Design Manual, chapter 3, linked-list code snippet confusion

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, function-pointers

I'm reading the Algorithm Design Manual and in chapter 3, the following code snippet appears. It has to do with removing an item from a linked-list. The question isn't related to data-structures, but just to a single line of code where two variables are declared *I think*. I've stripped the non-relevant parts of the code for brevity.

```
list *search_list(list *l, item_type x) {
  // This function just searches the list x
}

list *predecessor_list(list *l, item_type x) {
  // This function simply returns the predecessor of x or NULL
}

delete_list(list **l, item_type x) {
  list *p;     /* item pointer */
  list *pred;  /* predecessor pointer */

  list *search_list(), *predecessor_list(); // What are these declarations?

  p = search_list(*l,x);

  // Code to delete the node if found is here    
}
```

My question is in the `delete_list function`, specifically, the line `list *search_list(), *predecessor_list();`. What is happening on that line? I'm guessing it's a pointer to a function, but my understanding is you are supposed to declare the function pointer with the appropriate parameters. Also, assuming I am correct, why are those lines even needed?

Comment: i guess these are function declarations, (not prototypes, declarations). read here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5481685/2549281 , and i'm pretty sure they are not required. try to remove them.

Comment: The code works fine with them removed, however, at first glance, it's very strange. I read it as "search_list is a pointer to a function that returns a list" which makes no sense obviously.

Comment: Most of your question has been answered, so I'll just comment on the part where you said: "I'm guessing it's a pointer to a function". For future reference -- a pointer to a function would need parentheses around the `*` and the function-name: `list (*search_list)()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line in question,

```
list *search_list(), *predecessor_list();
```

informs the compiler that an `identifier` for a `function` exists and what its return type is. In this context, the number and type of parameter(s) the function requires is not needed.

I agree it's a bit peculiar and not very intuitive, however, the C language supports many such peculiarities.

The link provided in a comment to your question by Dabo goes into more detail: [Why does an empty declaration work for definitions with int arguments but not for float arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481579/whats-the-difference-between-function-prototype-and-declaration/5481685#5481685)

Answer (score 3):

Those are function declarations, to inform that `search_list()` and `predecessor_list()` return `list*`. If you use a function before you declare it, it is implicitly declared to be ‘function returning int’. In case functions `search_list()` and `predecessor_list()` defined before `delete_list` you won't need those declarations.

Try to put those functions after `delete_list` and remove declarations, you will get `conflicting types for search_list()` as your compiler will assume that `search_list()` and `predecessor_list()` should return `int`