# Why put void in params?

Tags: c++

What's the reason for putting void inside of the params?

Why not just leave it blank?

```
void createLevel(void);

void createLevel();
```

Comment: To make the language lawyers in your office stop nagging you annoyingly.

Comment: @Crashworks So people prefer having void?

Comment: @Crashworks: it won't let them shut up if you do C++. Putting `void` to indicate that no arguments shall be passed to the function is a C thing.

Comment: This question in answered for both C and C++ in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/c-void-arguments

Comment: possible duplicate of [C void arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/c-void-arguments)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `void` in the parenthesis are from C. In C a function with empty parentheses could have any number of parameters. In C++ it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I thought it was something like this, but my C is a little rusty.

Answer (score 18):

`void` in function argument lists is a relict of the past (C). In C++, you should leave the parentheses empty. Of course you can keep the `void` if it makes you happy.

In C, if you declare a function with empty parentheses, the meaning is that the number of parameters is unknown. `void` can be used to make it explicit that no parameters are expected.

Answer (score 13):

In C++ there is no difference.

The following applies only to C:

Actually, according to [this thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/c-declaring-void-parameters-289022/):

> when you declare somewhere a function func(), this means you don't say anything about it's aguments. On the otherhand func(void) means NO ARGUMENTS

perfect_circle even posted a wonderful code example to illustrate the point:

```
skalkoto@darkstar:~$ cat code.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        void func(void);
        func(3);
return 0;
}

void func(int a)
{
        printf("Nothing\n");
}
skalkoto@darkstar:~$ gcc code.c
code.c: In function `main':
code.c:6: error: too many arguments to function `func'
skalkoto@darkstar:~$ cat code1.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        void func();
        func(3);
        return 0;
}

void func(int a)
{
        printf("Nothing\n");
}
skalkoto@darkstar:~$ gcc code1.c
skalkoto@darkstar:~$ ./a.out
Nothing
skalkoto@darkstar:~$
```

Comment: I like this. Here I thought it was always a style thing.

Comment: Note that this answer applies to C, but not to C++. In C++, empty parentheses *always* means "no parameters".

Comment: @Greg - Thanks for the tip, I just updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference, this is just down to personal preference, e.g. to show yourself that when designing the function you didn't forget to give params.

Answer (score -1):

It's a preferential thing. Some people prefer to make things explicit instead of implicit. There is no practical difference between the two.

Comment: I wouldn't call an empty parameter list "implicit". It's not as if having no parameters is a special default behavior that kicks in when you, erm, list no parameters. Seems to me more like a preference for noisy over quiet ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Only put <strike>`VOID`</strike> `void` in params if you're old school (I do)

Comment: By the way, `VOID` all-caps is mostly a Win32 thing.