# how can I use c empty parentheses function, in c++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have a *C library* which use this *function prototype*, I want to *use it in C++*

```
int mlx_key_hook(void *win_ptr, int (*funct_ptr)(), void *param);
```

but in reality the function asked is

```
int funct_ptr(int keycode, void *param);
```

In fact I have this problem: [Why put void in params?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587207)

Then, I ask you how can I call this function with the appropriate *C++ funct_ptr* ?

Or have I to re-compil this lib after having changed the *funct_ptr prototype* ?

**This doesn't work:**

```
mlx_key_hook(win_ptr, [](int keycode, void *param) -> int {

    return 0;

}, NULL);
```

**This work but that's not what I want:**

```
mlx_key_hook(win_ptr, []() -> int {

    return 0;

}, NULL);
```

Comment: The C library is not expecting the 2-arg function pointer, so that is the reason the first one does not work. You have to ask for a new function accepting a function with an `int` and a `void*` parameter in the C lib.

Comment: You'll have to cast the function pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution would be to recompile your C++ code with a header that uses an appropriate function prototype, i.e.

```
int mlx_key_hook(void *win_ptr, int (*funct_ptr)(int keycode, void *param), void *param);
```

Then the code snippet with a lambda that takes two parameters will compile.

Another solution would be to use `reinterpret_cast`. Although it is not allowed to call a function with a reinterpreted signature (undefined behavior) casting a reinterpreted pointer back to its original signature before the call is allowed.

```
typedef int (*funct_ptr_good)(int, void *);
typedef int (*funct_ptr_bad)();

void foo(funct_ptr_bad fb) {
    // This is a C++ version of what your C library does
    funct_ptr_good fg = reinterpret_cast<funct_ptr_good>(fb);
    fg(12345, NULL);
}

int main() {
    funct_ptr_good fg = [] (int key, void * ptr) -> int {
        cout << key << " " << ptr << endl;
        return 0;
    };
    // foo expects a pointer that takes no parameters, in the same way that your C library does
    foo(reinterpret_cast<funct_ptr_bad>(fg));
    return 0;
}
```

The above prints `12345 0` ([demo](http://ideone.com/iDQH9R)).

Comment: Hoooon! You do a good answer ! GG ! I will try to do that, thank you :)

Comment: When you say ***The best solution would be to recompile your C++ code***, you mean ***The best solution would be to recompile your C library***, no ?

Comment: @Kerosene Recompiling C library with the new prototype will not change anything, because the trick "function declared with empty parentheses takes anything I pass" already works in C. The header for that function that you include in your C++ code is what's telling C++ of C library's expectations. C++ interprets the expected signature differently, though: empty parentheses mean strictly "no parameters" to C++. So it's only C++ code that needs the right signature, not the C code.

Comment: That work perfectly with `reinterpret_cast<funct_ptr_bad>(funct_ptr)` thank you very much ! Have a good day :)