# Getline equivalent for class and int, and also 'no viable overloaded =' error

Tags: c++, getline

```
class Book{
public:
string _title;
string _author;
string _publisher;
Date _published;
float _price;
string _isbn;
int _page;
int _copies;


Book(void);
Book(string, string, string, Date, float, string, int, int);
};

Book::Book(void)
{
 _title = "";
 _author = "";
 _publisher = "";
 _published = 0;
 _price = 0;
 _isbn = "";
 _page = 0;
 _copies = 0;
```

Where Date is a class including ints for day, month, and year. This generates a no viable overloaded = error.

```
int main(void)
{
LinkedList myList;
ifstream myFile("sample.txt");

string title;
string author;
string publisher;
Date published;
float price;
string isbn;
int page;
int copies;


while( myFile )
{
getline(myFile,title);
getline(myFile,author);
getline(myFile,publisher);
getline(myFile,published);
getline(myFile,price);
getline(myFile,isbn);
getline(myFile,page);
getline(myFile,copies);

myList.insert_rear(new    Book(title,author,publisher,published,price,isbn,page,copies));
}

myList.print_list();

return 0;
```

}

For getline published(Date class), price(int), page(int), and copies(int) I'm getting a no matching function call for getline. I know getline is for strings so I expected that error. What can I do instead?

Thank you, and if you need to see more code let me know.

Comment: `cin >> price;` etc? Usually people learn about `>>` before `getline`.

Comment: Not so trivial on this one @immibis. odds are way too good that some of those variable are going to be multi-word.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @user4581301 What is a multi-word `int`?

Comment: Please, format/indent your code legibly. Avoid [`using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). The `void` in `int main(void)` and similar is [pointless in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587207/why-put-void-in-params).

Comment: For the `int`  no, but mixing the `>>` and the `getline` needed to handle Author "John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt" has a couple caveats to go with it.

Comment: You can always overload `getline` for your classes or overload `operator >>` to read in a class.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews how would you implement that?

Comment: @WilliamStoneOtworth:  Create another [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function, but have it use your class as the 2nd parameter.  Inside the function, put code that reads the class members from the file.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot simply `std::getline` into an `int`. Seriously. It's harder than walking into Mordor.

A few ways to do this.

One is to intermix `std::getline` and use of the `>>` operator. But

```
myFile >> price;
getline(myFile,isbn);
```

Won't work because `myFile >> price;` leaves the end of line in the stream to be gobbled up by `getline(myFile,isbn)` resulting in an empty string in `isbn`. Something simple like

```
char end_of_line;
myFile >> price >> end_of_line;
getline(myFile,isbn);
```

will do the job, assuming your file strictly adheres to the format.

```
myFile >> price;
myFile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
getline(myFile,isbn);
```

is safer. It discards everything up to and including the end of the line.

Sadly you can't do this with `published` unless you've written an `operator>>` for `Date`.

The next good option is to read in everything as a string and then convert it to  the appropriate datatype before calling the `Book` constructor. Something along the lines of

```
int main()
{
    ifstream myFile("sample.txt");

    string title;
    string author;
    string publisher;
    string published;
    string price;
    string isbn;
    string page;
    string copies;

    while (getline(myFile, title) &&
           getline(myFile, author) &&
           getline(myFile, publisher) &&
           getline(myFile, published) &&
           getline(myFile, price) &&
           getline(myFile, isbn) &&
           getline(myFile, page) &&
           getline(myFile, copies))
    {
        myList.insert_rear(new Book(title,
                                    author,
                                    publisher,
                                    string_to_date(published), // function does not exist 
                                    stof(price),
                                    isbn,
                                    stoi(page),
                                    stoi(copies)));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Off topic: Note how all of the `getline`s are in the `while` this will not enter the body of the loop unless reading of all of the inputs succeeded.

```
while( myFile )
```

tests for goodness at the beginning before all of the values are read. All this tells you is the last thing you read was good. It give no guarantees about the quality of the next things you will read. Currently `getline(myFile,title);` could fail along with everything after it and you'll build the new `Book` with the results of invalid reads. Always read, test that you read good information, and only then use what you read.

Probably the best way is to take either of the above two methods and build them into an `operator>>` for `Book`.

Then you can

```
int main()
{
    ifstream myFile("sample.txt");

    Book temp;
    while (myFile >> temp)
    {
        myList.insert_rear(new Book(temp));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This even makes it easy to get rid of the dynmaically allocated `Book`, and that's worth it's weight in gold.

Comment: User4581301, the aforementioned tip works great for price, page, and copies, but will not work for published (date). Any other options for string_to_date(published), // function does not exist ? I have to use published as a class Date for this assignment. Sorry for the formatting errors, first time using this site.

Comment: @WilliamStoneOtworth i totally ignored `Date` because I have no clue what it looks like, how it stores information or what information it stores other than a date. It could be as simple as `Date string_to_date(string datestr) { return Date(datestr) }`. Even if you cannot modify Date, sometimes you can still write a `>>` for it off to the side. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading (Bookmark that link by the way. It's a real bacon-saver)