# Interview question and discussion in C

Tags: c, global-variables

This was the question asked to me in an interview in c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
  char *ch;
  ch=fun1();
  printf(ch);
}

fun1(){
  char *arr[100];
  strcpy(arr,"name");
  return arr;
}
```

I was given the above program and was asked to figure out the problems in the above code.
below was my answer

- function declaration is wrong.the
  return type should be `char **`
- syntax of `printf` is wrong
- `arr` scope is limited to the function `fun1`

then

***Interviewer*** : what would be your solution to the problem?

***Me***:  you need to make the arr variable as global and fix the remaining issues mentioned above.

***Interviewer***: Dont you think global variables are dangerous?

***Me***: Yes ofcourse,since  we cannot say where it is being accessed in which functions and sometimes it gets almost impossible to find which function has changed the value

***Ineterviewer*** :give me a solution without a global variable

***Me***:????

what would be your solution for this?
Could anybody pls point out the errors that i have made !!

Comment: First need to ask the interviewer what fun1 is intended to do.

Comment: Voting to close. You should learn C before applying for jobs writing C code.

Comment: You missed a whole bunch of other problems in the code.

Comment: that is what i want to know..could you pls list out some

Comment: I dont know why a closing vote.This question is a genuine question IMO.I just wanted to know where i am wrong and want to improve myself with the opinions of others.Whats wrong with this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My solution could be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* copies "name" to `dst`.
** The caller is responsible for making sure
** `dst` has enough space */
char *fun1(char *dst) {
  strcpy(dst, "name");
  return dst;
}

int main(void) {
  char ch[5];
  printf("%s\n", fun1(ch));
  return 0;
}
```

---

Here's just what I found about the snippet ...

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

I'd add a space before the header: `#include <stdio.h>`; but that's just for looks

```
void main()
```

WRONG! `main` returns an `int`. **ALWAYS!**
And it should be one of: `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` if you need parameters

```
{
char *ch;
ch=fun1();
```

No prototype for `fun1` in scope. This makes the compiler assume the function returns a value of type `int` and the statement tries to assign that value to an object of type `char*` which is illegal: the compiler must issue a diagnostic here.

```
printf(ch);
}

fun1()
```

In C99, it is mandatory to specify a return type; in C89, `int` is assumed. Also this function definition really should also be a prototype (in both C89 and C99) and specifiy the number and types of parameters (or `void` if it takes none).

```
{
char *arr[100];
```

Why do you need an array of 100 pointers? ???

```
strcpy(arr,"name");
```

Oops ... no prototype for `strcpy()` in scope. Also, assuming the `strcpy` is the one declared in `<string.h>`, the 1st parameter should be a `char*` not a `char **`

```
return arr;
```

`arr` ceases to exist right after the function returns. Its address (the array decays to the address of its first element in this context) is unusable in the calling code.

```
}
```

Comment: Well, adding void to mark an empty argument list is completely optional. Most people don't bother, since it adds no information.

Comment: @jforberg: not in C. The absence of `void` makes it **not** a prototype. The compiler cannot assume a function without a prototype takes no arguments. (I believe it is different in C++).

Comment: It adds the information that you really mean "void" and haven't just forgotten to include the parameters you really meant. Remember that code is written for programmer to read too, and clear, explicit code means fewer mistakes.

Comment: `strcpy(dst, "name");` - so you're trusting callers to guess how big the buffer has to be?

Comment: @pmg: Why would you want to prototype main()?
@Taryn: Well, it's a matter of style.

Comment: Yes, it's a matter of Good Style. One element of Good Style is "make errors obvious so it's more likely that you can spot them" - in this case, being explicit with parameters makes it obvious that you purposely chose to make this a void function - in that way - if you ever did just forget to add params (ie made an error)... it is obvious... because it's different to every other function definition in your file.

Comment: You claimed it added no information. I counter that it adds precisely the information that "this was done on purpose". ;)

Comment: Example of [prototypes in action](http://codepad.org/EtVX9vzV) LOL

Comment: @Georg: Yes, I trust the users! BUT (big BUT) I missed the documentation ... added to the code ... thanks

Comment: You could just allocate space inside the function taking in a pointer to avoid callers to have to know the size as Georg mentioned. Also why are your returning the char pointer in this case, can we just make it a void function since the function is changing the value itself.

Answer (score 2):

Either a `static char arr[100]` inside thefunction (this would lead to problems, because it would render it non reentrant) or you should `malloc()` the array and return its pointer (you should free it later in the caller function).

Don't wait for that company to call back ;)

Comment: Or at least *don't hold your breath* waiting for the company to call back.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
void fun1();

int main()
{
char *ch = malloc(sizeof(char) *100);
fun1(ch);
printf("%s\n", ch);
free(ch);
}

fun1 (char* ch)
{
    strcpy(ch,"name");
}
```

This is the best solution imo. There are obviously other ways to do it. You could declare `char arr[100]` and pass that in, then set ch = arr, but this basically cuts out the middleman.

Although I suppose this changes the problem format, so I'm not sure if that's allowed. If you have to maintain the structure, then `static char arr[100]` or `malloc()` in the function is the way to go.

Comment: why dont you declare ch as a local variable instead of using malloc in main? also I think to remember, that the standard of main looks something like "int main(void)"

Comment: You could do that too. I just scratched something together fast. int main() is an acceptable alternative.

Comment: @Christian: main(void) is simply a stylistic variation, like putting braces on a line of their own. The (void) adds no information, so is superfluous IMO.

Comment: I just found a thread about this and the discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/c-void-arguments points out, that the version with explicit (void) may have some benefits in C.

Comment: @Christian: I'm not saying it's wrong; I'm saying it's a matter of taste. Your arguments have merit, but the usage of (void) is not strictly relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least the following additional errors:

1. The return type of `main()` should be `int`, if you're following modern standards.
2. The `puts()` function should be used instead of `printf()`, since no formatting is performed.
3. The variable `arr` should probably have type `char*`, not `char**` (a single string vs. and array of 100 strings.)
4. `fun1()` is called before it is declared & defined, which is an error. In a real project, you would have a forward-declaration in a header file which accompanies you program code.
5. The program, in its current form, *does nothing at all*.

You should start by asking your interviewer: "What is the program supposed to do?" before you try to fix it, IMO. If the point is to output "name" to std output, the following code suffices, and is much simpler (that is, *better*):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    puts("name");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

static declaration of arr in function

```
static char arr[100];
```

this way its still local to function, and you can return a valid pointer to it.

btw, fun1 return type should be `char*`, not `char**`

Comment: why it should not be char **?

Comment: the array is a array of char pointers which is a valid c array.why are you changing it to char arr[100]

Comment: -1: ick - this is non-reentrant

Comment: I'm sorry but this is wrong. fun1 should not return char.

Comment: @Rahul Dravid the array of pointers is clearly a trap here, dont know the behaviour of app in this case

Comment: @Rahul: Pick up whatever C book or online resource you're using, and check the argument types of strcpy(). It's not valid C to pass it a char**.

Comment: Thanks for voting me down, anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

Hence the string returned by the function `fun1` is fixed,
`func1` can return a `const char*` type.
The string `"name"` will be stored in read only area
and its pointer will be returned.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  const char *ch;
  ch=fun1();
  printf("%s", ch);
  return 0;
}
const char *fun1(){
  const static char* arr[] = "name";
  return arr;
}
```

You will be able to write as below:

```
const char *fun1(){
  return "name";
}
```

Comment: Or just remove the darn function altogether... The program still isn't good/valid C because main() doesn't return int. And what is the type of arr?