# why static flag instead of static int flag doesnot give any error?

Tags: c

see once in hurry i have written

```
#include <stdio.h>

static flag;            
int main()
{
printf("flag is %d",flag);
return 0;
}
```

it does not not give any warning or error and works fine. I dont understand why this is going work?

Comment: This is one of weird things in C. Like [what `int main()` actually means](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/c-void-arguments).

Comment: @ mr.downvoter can you say me reason ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C assumes `int` when type is missing. It is also true for function definitions and their parameters:

```
// same as int add(int x, int y)
add(x,y) { return x + y; }

// same as int main()
main()
{
}
```

Comment: So I can declare my integers with just `flag;`? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Apparently, there have to be at least either storage specifier or type, you can't omit both, though my GCC accepts that (with warning).

Answer (score 3):

Staic is always default as a int and static int is 0 ..

Answer (score 1):

When `int` is used in conjunction with another keyword, `int` is optional

```
static int  <--> static
volatile int  <--> volatile
short int <--> short
long int <--> long
```

While `short` and `long` are accepted short forms, you should avoid leaving it out in conjunction with storage keywords (`static`, `volatile`).

Answer (score 1):

Primary datatypes are

```
char , int , float , double
```

the Storage classes like

```
auto,static,extern etc
```

data type modifiers like

```
long,signed,unsigned etc,
```

if the storage classes or datatype modifiers miss the primary datatype of the variable then the compiler treats them as integer by default and even if function return types
are not defined they are treated as int by default

example

```
long i is similar to long int i
static i is similar to static int i
```

But you cant simply say i and ask why compiler doesnt treat it as int

Answer (score -1):

flag is initialized to 0, as a global static variable. other languages like Java will give an error if you try to use an uninitialized variable. i'm assuming this is C, in which case flag defaults to type int. please don't ever do this. it's really bad programming practice.