# Why prototype and definition of a function in C may differ?

Tags: c

I'm wondering why this will compile:

```
int test();

int main() { return test((void*)0x1234); }
int test(void* data) { return 0; }
```

Why won't the compiler emit any error/warning about that (I tried clang, gcc)?
If I change the return value it won't compile - but the arguments may differ?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C void arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/c-void-arguments)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you change:

```
int test();
```

to:

```
int test(void);
```

you will get the expected error:

```
foo.c:4: error: conflicting types for ‘test’
foo.c:1: error: previous declaration of ‘test’ was here
```

This is because `int test();` simply declares a function which takes *any* parameters (and is therefore compatible with your subsequent definition of `test`), whereas `int test(void);` is an actual function prototype which declares a function which takes *no* parameters (and which is *not* compatible with the subsequent definition).

Comment: +1, to state it in C-ish terminology, `int test()` simply isn't a prototype but just a declaration.

Comment: But such behavior will be soon deprecated (or at least this is what ISO C11 tell us).

Answer (score 15):

```
 int test();
```

in a function declaration, no parameter means the function takes an unspecified number of arguments.

This is different than

```
 int test(void);
```

which means the function takes no argument.

A function declaration with no parameter is the old C style of function declaration;  C marks this style as obsolescent and discourages its use. In short, don't use it.

In your case, you should use a function declaration with the correct parameter declaration:

```
 int test(void *data);
```

Comment: I always forget C does that! Even if it was `int test(void);` but cross TU there's no requirement for a diagnostic to be issued though.