# Using an array defined outside of function from inside the function

Tags: c, arrays, function

I define an array and a function. The array is defined outside of the function. But I also have to use this inside the function.  What do I need to do?

```
uint8_t array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

myfunction(){
   //call index #2 of array
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by outside of the function?Global?In main?

Comment: Functions can be called. Arrays cannot be called.  Arrays can be accessed.  We have yet to see a description of a problem or a question.

Comment: You can't "call" an array. You can call a function. And yes, you can use a global variable inside a function.

Comment: What do you mean by "call" the array? You can refer to it: `a[2]`, and assign to it: `a[2] = 10`.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. But those two answers where the solution, global scope is the keyword.

Comment: @M.Zim: It is not. The answerers are imprecise at best, technically they are wrong. There is no such thing like "global scope" in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. The array you declared has global scope, so it is available inside the function.

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

void myfunction(){
   printf("element is %d",arr[1]); //This is perfectly valid
}
```

Comment: I am also not the down voter, and I am not sure what compiler you are using, but when I create, and try to use `myfunction` with the form you have, it fails. I am using a C99 compiler.   The prototype should be `void myfunction(void);`, (not `void myfunction();`).

Comment: @ryyker Are you using a C++ compiler or old C compiler.  `void myfunction()` should be OK.

Comment: @chux -  I am using a 2017 implementation of C99 (ANSI C), it is a National  Instruments implementation.  The error msg may be because I have the "require prototypes" option set, and it does not recognize the prototype without the void in the parenthesis.  I tried it both ways, it will not compiler without the `void`

Comment: @ryyker [empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12022875/2410359) may help.

Comment: @chux - good reference.  And I tried it on  my system with the prototype: `void func(void);`, but the definition: void func(){...}` and it did not complain.   Since this answer is just showing the definition, I agree its perfectly valid.  Thanks,

Comment: There is nothing like "global scope".

Comment: @Olaf I wrote it to make him understand that. What I meant was that the array is available globally

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan: It is not. You confuse scope and linkage. These are two different fundamental concepts of C. Unless you pointed out their difference, you add to OPs apparent confusion.

Comment: @Olaf In that case, I request you to edit my answer and all relevant content. It will help OP as well as me.

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan: This is not my answer and I will not answer for you; The standard is quite clear and not taht complicated to read.