# What does it mean when a C function pointer has a void parameter?

Tags: c, function, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C void arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/c-void-arguments)

I am looking at some OpenGL graphics code and it has the following:

```
glutIdleFunc(void(*func)(void));
```

When does it mean to have a function pointer with a void argument in C? Does this mean the function can take in any arguments or is not allow to take in any arguments, or something else?

Comment: It means that the function takes no arguments. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/693794/275567).

Comment: It's a function pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing. Note that the function pointer may be casted and this may be only a place holder for arbitrary function pointers to be passed to the function `glutIdleFunc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you have to pass a pointer to a function that has no parameters and returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`void func(void)` 
is a function that takes no parameters and does not `return` anything.

This is not to be confused with:
`void func()` 
which in C (not C++) is a function that has no parameter checking, and does not `return` anything.

This is not to be confused with:
`func(void)`
which is a function which takes no parameters and returns an `int`, by default.