# Conflicting types in C

Tags: c

I was trying to build a very simple program in C that returns a float value from a function, but for some reason I got an error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    double returning;
    returning = regre();
    printf("%f", returning);
    return 0;
}
double regre(){
    double re = 14.35;
    return re;
}
```

The error am getting says:

> conflicting types for 'regre'
>
> previous implicit declaration of regre was here

Comment: if i replace in the regre function doble for int type the program runs... but i need to return a double from a function.

Comment: You should declare the function before you use it.

Comment: Note: Maybe unlike to you are thinking, `double regre()` make a function with undefined number of arguments of unknow types. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/c-void-arguments

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That error message is telling you exactly what's happening - there is an implicit declaration of `regre` because you don't define it until after `main()`.  Just add a forward declaration:

```
double regre();
```

Before `main()`, or just move the whole function up there.

Comment: thanks a lot! i didnt know that! this is my first program in c using functions... thanks!!!

Comment: @elizabeth - if you're a beginner, and it sure sounds like you are, you might want to check out [clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org).  The error messages from clang are a lot better than most compilers, and that will help you get started.

Answer (score 2):

```
previous implicit declaration of `regre` was here
```

If a function is unknown, then compiler considers it as `int functionname()` by default. In your case `int regre()` will be declared here.

```
conflicting types for 'regre'
```

When your actual function `double regre()` is noticed, this conflict error occurs. To solve this issue, double regre() function should be declared before it's actual use.

```
#include<stdio.h>
double regre(); //Forward Declaration
int main(){
    double returning;
    returning = regre();
    printf("%f", returning);
    return 0;
}
double regre(){
    double re = 14.35;
    return re;
}
```

For more info on Forward Declaration, refer the following link.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration

Answer (score 0):

In C whenever your using a function by either call by value or call by reference , those functions by default they will be int type . When your using any function which is the type of it for that you need to define the function prototype in the program before calling that function .
The best way is just define all the function prototype before the main it self that is the good way of programming . 
Coming to your program just define the prototype as double regre(); befor main

```
double regre();
    main()
      {
```