# 3rd function won't run scanf

Tags: c

I have a simple program which receives input from 3 different functions, 2 return ints, 1 returns a char, but the third function doesn't scanf for some reason it skips that step entirely.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_height();
int get_length();
char get_symbol();
void draw_rectangle(int h, int l, char s);

int main () {

    int h, l;
    char s;

    h = get_height();
    l = get_length();
    s = get_symbol();

    draw_rectangle(h, l, s);

    return 0;
}

int get_height() {

    int i;

    printf ("Please enter the height of the rectangle: ");
    scanf ("%d", &i);

    return i;
}

int get_length() {

    int i;

    printf ("Please enter the length of the rectangle: ");
    scanf ("%d", &i);

    return i;
}

char get_symbol() {

    char i;

    printf ("Please enter the symbol for the rectangle: ");
    scanf ("%c", &i);

    return i;
}

void draw_rectangle(int h, int l, char s) {
    printf ("%d %d %c", h, l, s);
}
```

When I run this, i can scan for height and length but it prints the prompt to scan for the char but then skips the user input and prints the value for h and l but no s. What am i missing here?

Comment: Write `void` in brackets after a function name if it doesn't take arguments.

Comment: @yzb3 '[' and ']' are brackets; '(' and ')' are known as *parentheses*.

Comment: Jim, seriously :D? @H2CO3 [C void arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/c-void-arguments)

Comment: @yzb3 Yes, seriously (I know why, but the C way of the interpretation is insane [one of the rare things C++ does better than C]).

Comment: @H2CO3 My "seriously" was directed at Jim Balter.

Comment: we call `[]` square braces, `{}` curly braces and `<>` angle braces in short.

Comment: British style is calling `()` brackets and `[]` square brackets :].

Answer (score 3):

Previous scanf leaves a newline in the input buffer which is consumed by:

```
scanf ("%c", &i);
```

Just change it to:

```
scanf (" %c", &i);
```

Notice the space. This will tell scanf to ignore all whitespaces.

Answer (score 2):

You need to consume the newline characters that are being left by the previous `scanf()` calls. A simple way would be:

```
scanf ("%d", &i);
getchar();
```

in each function where it's used. Or with just the one call:

```
scanf(" %c", &i);
```

the space will tell it to skip the previous tabs, newlines, or spaces.

`stdin` is buffered and when the user enters a digit you get a newline char too. The scanf taking the character is therefore picking up one of those left over newlines

Comment: Wouldn't the pattern "%d\n" accomplish the same thing without requiring a second function call?

Comment: @PeterGluck - Not exactly. That's going to cause the newline to be skipped as input but the scanf will keep waiting (you hit `<digit><enter>` and it still waits for input), it will work oddly from the users perspective. The getchar() will consume the newline from the stream. The other 1 function option is to put a space before the `%c` which will tell scanf to ignore the previous newlines, tabs, and spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%c",&i);
```

It will resolve your problem. As fflush clears the buffer before reading the character