# No compile error regarding wrong function parameters

Tags: c, gcc

I have simple programm in two units:

count_words.c:

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    printf("starting\n");
    int i =  aaa(55555);
    printf("%d",i);
    printf("ending\n");
    return i;
}
```

clean.c:

```
int aaa()
{
    printf("aaa\n");
    return 5;
}
```

Makefile:

```
count_words:  clean.o count_words.o  -lfl
        gcc count_words.o clean.o -lfl -ocount_words 

%.o:%.c
        gcc -c -o $@ $<
```

I'm wondering why this code compiles and runs without problem. Function `aaa()` in `clean.c` has no parameters, but in `count_words.c` I pass `55555`. Why it compiles and runs. Can I expect unexpected errors in such situations?

UPD:

I have changed  `int aaa()` to `int aaa(void)`, but still have warning and not error.

As you noticed I didn't include header of `clean.c` in `count_words.c` and it compiles anyway. Why then I must include headers at all?

Comment: You have to declare a function with no parameters as `aaa(void)`. Otherwise it is not standard compliant.

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages!

Comment: And it is pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726506/how-to-let-gcc-warn-unmatched-number-of-arguments-when-making-function-calls

Comment: `int aaa()` does not have "no parameters". It has undefined parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The program has undefined behaviour.

According to the C Standard (6.5.2.2 Function calls)

> 6. ..If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the behavior is undefined.

The function is defined as having no parameters but is called with one argument.

From the C Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))

> 14....An empty list in a function declarator **that is part of a definition** of
>   that function specifies that **the function has no parameters**.

In C++ this code will not compile.