# difference of datatypes used before main() function

Tags: program-entry-point

What is the beneficial effects and difference between using main() function as

- `void main()`

  or
- `int main(void)`

Comment: you should always use int main(), because upon finishing the application, the OS need to know the exit status of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A main function is called by a pre-load library that runs upon execution by the operating system. Many operating systems handle the result of an executable - and declaring main to return a type of `int` means that the main function can return a value. Obviously declaring main to return a type of `void` means that the main function cannot return a value - and some compilers will not permit this depending on what the target architecture of your build is.

The difference between declaring a function `()` or `(void)` is documented many times [elsewhere on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/c-void-arguments).

Comment: isn't it a just for the standardization of C and C++ that many compilers wouldn't allow void main() ?

Comment: @AmanSingh I've used void main in my past. But that's a long past. I can't remember `gcc` letting me use void main in recent years.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your application to have the ability to return a value, you must use

`int main(void)`.

Answer (score -2):

First is wrong, second is correct. End of story.