# why does a pointer to a function not enforce that method's signature

Tags: c

I'm trying to pick up blocks in objective-c and am learning about pointers to functions so this might be a really obvious question. I compiled the following in Xcode 5 and have the following:

```
void hearThis(char * (*pFunc)(char *myString)){
 /*
  why does it allow me to do this? when signature for 
   helpMe doesn't take an argument
  */
    char *str=(*pFunc)("what I want as arg"); 
    printf("you are going to hear this: %s\n", str);
}


char * helpMe(){
  return "this is from helpMe";
}

int main(){
    char * (*fNewFunc)();
    fNewFunc=&helpMe;
    // we are passing a pointer to a function
    hearThis(fNewFunc);
```

which outputs:

```
you are going to hear this: this is from helpMe
```

Why does it allow me to even compile when it is passing an argument to a function that doesn't take one OR not crash when run?

Comment: In C, declaring a function with no parameters _must_ be declared with `void` parameters.  e.g., `char * (*fNewFunc)(void);`  If declared without parameters, you're declaring _a_ function with _unspecified parameters_.  It's not the same.

Comment: See also: [C void arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/693788/390278)

Comment: thx Jeff, I forgot about that

Comment: @JeffMercado that's valid for ANSI C, in C99 `char * helpMe()` is the same as `char *helpMe(void)`

Comment: @Marco where does the standard state that?

Comment: @Marco is `gcc --std=c11` in error then? Calling `char*helpMe()` with `helpMe("test")` compiles silently, with `char*helpMe(void)` it warns.

Comment: @Marco: It is _deprecated_ to use the parameterless version in C99, it's still not the same.

Comment: @JeffMercado have you considered giving your first comment as an answer? As it is I can only upvote your comment, even though the question is just an oversight it seems to me it's worth an answer on SO.

Comment: what? in C99 you should use int func(); instead of int func(void); =/

Comment: @Marco No, they are not the same, and you should always specify a parameter list.

Comment: Hm.. I will delete my answer until I read a bit about that. I was sure that it was the other way around.

Comment: @jthill: Usually when I see a C question involving a function with an empty parameter list, I can immediately tell that the problem is going to be due to some misunderstanding on what it really means. And when I post answers, I generally try to explain everything, something I just didn't have the time for right now. I might have if I had more time but it's not a big deal for me if someone else does.

Comment: thx for your help Jeff. I haven't touched real C in many years and don't think every pointers to functions. Thx again

Comment: @effeffe Apparently `char *helpMe() { return "this is from helpMe"; }` is the same as `char *helpMe(void) { return "this is from helpMe"; }` in C99 and later.

Comment: @Marco Try to call that function with arguments.

Comment: @effeffe I'm refering to what the standard (for c99 and c11) says. Read: §6.7.5.3.14 `An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a deﬁnition of that function speciﬁes that the function has no parameters.`

Comment: @Marco Wait, sorry for the confusion, your last example is different from the first one you made: `void foo();` and `void foo(void);` are different because they're not definitions, just declarations; `void foo() { }` and `void foo(void) { }` are also definitions and therefore they are the same.

Comment: @effeffe Yeah, but the last example is the same case that this question.. So the problem is not with helpMe but with the function that casts. It IS undefined behaviour after all. On the other hand, why can you call foo with arguments ? compiler doesn't follow the standard?

Comment: @Marco The program does not contain any cast, which line do you think it's invoking UB exactly?

Comment: Look at my answer @effeffe. The undefined behaviour happens when calling `pFunc` from `hearThis`. The function types are incompatible (that says gcc), causing an undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Marco Oh, now I see what you mean: since you were talkin' about "casts" (and btw these are just implicit conversions, not casts) I didn't understand you were referring to *that* function call, my bad. Good point, I agree with you on the UB call, +1 to your answer.

Comment: @jthill I think that gcc and clang are both wrong :( they should display a warning. Maybe it is woth reporting, the thing is that using an empty parameter list is deprecated, so maybe they won't even bother. BTW, I have edited my answer after reading the standard.

Comment: @Marco It's possible to get some warnings about missing parameter list in function declaration, with appropriate warning settings. gcc can do it.

Comment: @effeffe Afaik, those warnings are for function prototypes, but old-style function declarations which aren't prototypes don't get those :( There are some warnings on clang, but on gcc I couldn't find a way to get a warning. As it has been said before, the best is to avoid old-style function declarations :P (I still think it looks better :( )

Comment: @Marco `-Wstrict-prototypes`, for example, gives a warning for the OP's code, wich goes away if you explicitly add `void` as parameter list. There are also more pedant warning options. But yeah, it's best to avoid this declarations at all.

Comment: @effeffe the thing with strict-prototypes is that it warns you if you don't use function prototypes (i.e: it warns you to avoid using old-style declarations). So, the warning is for a different reason. The definition without the void parameter is totally valid and one would think that the compiler should throw a warning because that's undefined behaviour :P

Comment: @Marco oh well, that kind of UB is impossible to catch for a compiler, sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C syntax for a function declaration taking no arguments is `f(void)`.  Your `fNewFunc` is to a function taking unspecified arguments.  Replace its declaration with

```
char * (*fNewFunc)(void);
```

and C can then at least warn you about the mismatch.  C++ will reject it.

**edit**: as chux points out in comments, the `char *helpMe()` definition, since it is a definition, does declare that `helpMe` takes no parameters, so there's no strict need to change it.

Comment: This appears _almost_ correct.  C11dr §6.7.6.3 14 "... An **empty
list** in a function declarator that is **part of a definition** of that function specifies that the function has **no parameters**. The **empty list** in a function declarator that is **not part of a definition** of that function **specifies that no information** about the number or types of the parameters is supplied."  (My emphasis.)  In OP's code, `helpMe()` is the same as `helpMe(void)` as its part of the definition and not a bare declaration.

Comment: @chux my mistake, though fortunately for OP it makes no difference here (the assignment being filtered through the no-parameters `fNewFunc` declaration.  Thanks for the correction, editing it in now.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have checked the **c99** standard and can say that this is **undefined behaviour**.

---

**TL;DR:** It is ok to cast/convert one function pointer to another type, but if you call that function, the function types must be compatible, otherwise, you get **undefined behaviour**. You don't get a warning because in each step you are converting between compatible function types, but in the end, `helpMe` isn't compatible with `pFunc`.

---

First of all:

```
char *helpMe(){
  return "this is from helpMe";
}
```

Is valid and in C99 is the same as:

```
char *helpMe(void){
  return "this is from helpMe";
}
```

From **§6.7.5.3** (emphasis mine):

> An identiﬁer list declares only the identiﬁers of the parameters of
>   the function. **An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a
>   deﬁnition of that function speciﬁes that the function has no
>   parameters**. The empty list in a function declarator that is not part
>   of a deﬁnition of that function speciﬁes that no information about the
>   number or types of the parameters is supplied.

I don't know how this behaves in C89, I think that maybe, in C89 that is valid.

On the other hand, we have:

```
char * (*fNewFunc)() = helpMe;
```

This cast is valid, because you can cast a function pointer to a function of another type and go back without problem. The compiler won't throw a warning because even their types are compatible! (void against unespecified).

Section **§6.3.2.3**, paragraph 8 reads (again, emphasis mine):

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   function of another type and back again; the result shall compare
>   equal to the original pointer. **If a converted pointer is used to call
>   a function whose type is not compatible with the pointed-to type, the
>   behavior is undefined.**

So, when you pass the pointer to `hearThis` it is casted again, from `char *(*)();` to `char *(*)(char *);` which, again, they are compatible for the compiler (thus, not throwing a warning).

**BUT** the standard says if the function type you are calling is incompatible with the function type pointed to, then, the **behaviour is undefined**.

Te question now is, are they compatible?

The answer is **NO**. if you change the type of `fNewFunc()` to `char *(*fNewFunc)(void);` you will get a warning:

```
p.c: In function ‘main’:
p.c:12:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘hearThis’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
p.c:6:6: note: expected ‘char * (*)(char *)’ but argument is of type ‘char * (*)(void)’
```

In the standard there also says when two functions types are compatible. It is in **§6.7.5.3.15**. It's a bit more complicated than this :P

#### Why does it work?

Probably it works because the computer doesn't care. It just pushes or passes the parameters as registers, and `helpMe` just ignores them. But you should know that it is **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: +1 for the C99 §6.7.5.3 (C11dr §6.7.6.3 14).  LSNED.