# Why these C++ cases instantiate different templates

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, function-signature

I am trying to write some functionality where I need to save different functions and later extract their arguments' types. So I'm using the function signature as template parameter. But I get somewhat unexpected results.
Here's the code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct foo
{
    foo()
    {
        std::cout << "class T" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class Ret, class Arg>
struct foo<Ret(Arg)>
{
    foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Ret(Arg)" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class T>
void save(std::function<T>)
{
    new foo<T>();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::function<void(void)> someFoo;
    save(someFoo);
    return 0;
}
```

So if the variable `someFoo` is a function with type `void(void)`, it instantiates the first template, `foo<T>`. But if I change it to `void(int)`, than I get the desired specialized template instantiated. Why is that?

Comment: `void(void)` is the same as `void()`. The second parameter of the specialization can't be matched so it falls back to the primary template.

Comment: Might want to check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/c-void-arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, having a `void` argument is actually the same as having no argument at all (unlike in C, by the way). So it would match a specialization for `Ret()`, but it can't match a specialization for `Ret(Arg)`.

Comment: Whats the difference in `c`?

Comment: @maja check my comment above in the question

Comment: In C, a `void` argument is the only way to tell you've no argument. If you put nothing between the parenthesis, it means you've an undefined number of arguments.

Answer (score 3):

`void(void)` is the exact same as `void()` - the second `void` is optional and makes no difference.

That's why the first template with no parameters is used.