# In C++, what does (void) do in parameters?

Tags: c++, methods, void

I have a line of code that looks like this:

```
int method(void) const;
```

But I'm not sure what (void) does in parameters, or what const does either. This is also supposed to be a public 'get' and I'm not sure how to approach (void) and const in classes.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't do anything. [It is a carry-over from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/c-void-arguments) which indicates (in C++) that the function takes no arguments. The following signature is equivalent

```
int method() const;
```

The `const` following the name of the function means that (since this implies the function is a class method) the function is not allowed to change any of the member variables of the class instance.

To implement a "setter" and "getter" you typically have something like this

```
class Foo()
{
public:
    int GetX() const  { return x; }   // getter method
    void SetX(int x_) { x = x_; }     // setter method
private:
    int x;
}
```

Notice that we can declare the getter `const` because it does not modify the value of `x`, but the setter cannot be `const` because the whole purpose of the method is to assign a new value to `x`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Sorry if I couldn't find this answer somewhere else.