# function which takes no parameters Vs function which takes parameter

Tags: c, function

I was educated from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/693883) that

```
void f();
void f(int a) {
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

the parameter type list "wins".
I did the following...

```
int fun(void); //parameter type list
int fun(int a, double b)//parameter type list
{
    printf("%d, %f", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting that compiler will throw an error (since overloading is not possible in c), but it didn't

Can anyone help me in this regards?

Thanks.

Comment: what compiler are you using. It should definitely throw an error.. `error: conflicting types for ‘fun’`

Comment: Which comes with VS2013

Comment: Yes you are correct, it is throwing an error. I checked in gcc. But why VS is not doing so?

Comment: @RachanaPal Are you sure that you're compiling with a VS C compiler, rather than C++?

Comment: Are you maybe compiling it in C++ mode?

Comment: @Jashaszun AFAIR it's the same compiler, distinguishing only by file name (extension). And visual studio doesn't provide an easy way (aka wizard) to create a `.c` file.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yeah it does... you can create a new file -> select "New C++ File", and then in the file name box enter something that ends with ".c". Now you have a C file that it compiles with the C compiler.

Comment: @RachanaPal ... "wins" is wrong: the declaration `void f();` just doesn't say anything about the parameters, that's perfectly valid but *bad practice*

Comment: @Jashaszun sure, that's what I do when I need it. But notice the "New **C++** File" ... it's like MS is trying to keep VS users from coding in [tag:c].

Comment: @FelixPalmen Ah sorry, I thought that you actually didn't know how to do it. Yeah, I agree, it is weird that they don't have a "New C File" option.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Visual Studio, the most likely reason for your situation is that your code is in a C++ file. Note that VS distinguishes between C and C++ files based on the file extension. Changing your file to a `.c` file rather than a `.cpp` file should do the trick.

(Note that when you `Add New Item` to create a source file, you can create a C file simply by adding a new C++ file and then changing the name of the created file to be `.c`, as in the image below.)

[image: Add New Item Dialog]