# Returning wrong address from the function

Tags: c

I have 3 files

`a.h`:

```
Struct a{ int I;}
```

`b.c`:

```
#include "a.h"
Main(){
    Struct a *b= hello();
}
```

`C.c`:

```
#include"a.h"
Struct a *hello(){
    Struct a *c= malloc (size of *(*c));
    c->I = 100;
    Return c;
}
```

And compiling .H file first ,then c.c file then b.c file,so here when main calls hello() function and it is returning c value address is correct while I am assigning to b,it is giving wrong address ,for example c value is 0x10322345 then b is 0xffff345 like this.....

Comment: `Main()`? rEALYY?

Comment: This is not a valid C syntax.

Comment: Your code is so very wrong...suggesting a good C book first...

Comment: See don't consider case sensitivity

Comment: @Rahulsurya yeah? who told you that? `The above tokens (case sensitive) are reserved....` C11, §6.4.1, go figure...

Comment: nor spaces... `size of`.. I don't understand how can you even ask this question considering the above.

Comment: 1) That's not the code you ran. Only post code that you've actually ran. 2) You called `hello` without declaring it, so it was implicitly declared as `int hello();`

Comment: `size of *(*c)` ==> `sizeof *(*c)` but It can't compile.

Comment: `Struct a *c= malloc (size of *(*c));` ==> `struct a *c = malloc(sizeof *c);`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, always turn on your compiler's warnings! With `gcc`, this is done by passing

```
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

Although, oddly enough, the warning in question is on by default in `gcc`, so you should have seen something like

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6:14: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

If you don't understand a warning, don't ignore it! Ask about it instead.

---

You called `hello` without declaring it, so it was implicitly declared as `int hello();`

`a.h`:

```
typedef struct { int i; } a_t;

a_t* hello(void);
```

`a.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "a.h"

a_t* hello(void) {
    a_t* a = malloc(sizeof(a_t));
    a->i = 100;
    return a;
}
```

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "a.h"

int main(void) {
    a_t* a = hello();
    printf("%d\n", a->i);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main main.c a.c && main
100
```

Comment: You should use `(void)` instead of simply `()`

Comment: @ikegami [Is it better to use C void arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/is-it-better-to-use-c-void-arguments-void-foovoid-or-not-void-foo)

Comment: @ikegami  It's not wrong, but unnecessary; functions are extern by default

Comment: @Erik W, Thanks.