# Compiler warning - something differs in parameter lists

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, cl

I'm trying to compile the following source code which successfully compiles on both `gcc` and Microsoft's `cl.exe`.

```
void SomethingBeforeExit();

void SomethingBeforeExit()
{
    // some code
    _exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // some code
    atexit(SomethingBeforeExit);
}
```

However, I'm getting a [C4113 warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38xttckh.aspx) from `cl.exe` with the following message:

```
SomeCode.c(10): warning C4113: 'void (__cdecl *)()' differs in parameter lists from 'void (__cdecl *)(void)'
```

As I said, the source code *still compiles successfully* and appears to work. My goal is to prevent this warning from happening in `cl`, as `gcc` doesn't generate any warnings upon compilation.

I assume that the declaration of that function is not being treated as `void SomethingBeforeExit(void)`, however, I don't know how to specifically declare a function's parameter list as `void`.

I'm using `VS14` and `C/C++ 19.00.23918 for x86` for `cl.exe` and `gcc v5.4.0` compilers to compare generated warnings.

Comment: The rule is pretty clear that the function you pass to `atexit` must be `(void)`. For historical reasons, `()` is not equivalent to `(void)` in (some versions of) C as it is in C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it better to use C void arguments "void foo(void)" or not "void foo()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/is-it-better-to-use-c-void-arguments-void-foovoid-or-not-void-foo)

Comment: @Downvoter not a direct duplicate question, I just didn't know how `()` declaration was treated as @David Schwartz stated. This question is about the `C4113` warning specifically which is related to incorrect parameter passing, not whether using `(void)` is better than `()`.

Comment: Which _line_ generated the waring: `atexit(SomethingBeforeExit);` or `void SomethingBeforeExit()
{`  ?

Comment: @chux the first one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C, empty parentheses in a function declaration doesn't mean "no parameters." Instead, it means any number of parameters (similar to `...` in C++). Perhaps what you meant to declare was `void SomethingBeforeExit(void)`.

Comment: Thank you, that's the correct answer. I failed to realize that `identifier2` in the MS documentation referred to the passed parameters.

Answer (score 2):

OP is not using a compliant C99/C11 compiler.  The code is valid C (C99/C11).

```
// declares function SomethingBeforeExit and no info about it parameters.
void SomethingBeforeExit();

// declares/defines function SomethingBeforeExit and 
// indirectly specifies the parameter list is `(void)`
// This does not contradict the prior declaration and so updates the parameter signature.
void SomethingBeforeExit() {
   ...  
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  ...
  // `atexit() expects a `void (*f)(void))`
  atexit(SomethingBeforeExit);
```

In C89 the `void SomethingBeforeExit() { ...}` definition still says nothing about the parameter list.  This is likely the cause of OP's problem.

To fix:

```
void SomethingBeforeExit(void) { 
  ...
}
```

The prior `void SomethingBeforeExit();` declaration need not update, yet would be in good to also update that so parameter checking can happen with code that does not see the definition.

Comment: The definition `void SomethingBeforeExit(){ … }` still doesn't provide a prototype for the function.  The compiler needn't complain if you invoke `SomethingBeforeExit(1, 3.14159, "Apocalypse Then"):` as there is no prototype in scope to make it invalid.

Comment: As I read C11 §6.7.6.3 14 "An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters." indicates the function takes no parameters - aka `(void)`. The `void SomethingBeforeExit( etc.` (as declaration/definition) at least prototypes the function as returning nothing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well at least my gcc version 5.4.0 agrees with you.

Comment: 100% agreed that the return type is declared — that was part of the compatibility with pre-standard C, of course.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I used `#define info_type(X) _Generic((X), \
  void (*)(void): "void (*)(void)", \
  int: "int", \
  default: "?" \
  )` and `void SomethingBeforeExit() {
}

void SomethingBeforeExitV(void) {
}` and `puts(info_type(SomethingBeforeExit));
  puts(info_type(SomethingBeforeExitV));` and both print `"void (*)(void)"`.  So with/without `void` make for the same function type, yet gcc only complains about `SomethingBeforeExitV(1)` and not `SomethingBeforeExit(1)` - Hmmm.  - An interesting finding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151003/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-chux).

Comment: The chat contains the details and much discussion, but it appears that §6.9.1 Function definitions, ¶7 does mean that the function definition `SomeType FunctionName() { … }` does not provide a prototype for the function, even though the compiler knows it is a function that takes no arguments.  The reason is probably 'historical' and/or 'it makes the language grammar easier to parse'.  Warnings could be generated by the compiler on misuse; that would be a QoI (quality of implementation) issue.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler and I have agreed on all points aside form we differ on "SomeType FunctionName() { … } provides a prototype or not".  IAC, we agree that `SomeType FunctionName(void) { … }` is better.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Further research bring me closer to your "SomeType FunctionName() { … } does not provide a prototype for the function".  I'd say now `SomeType FunctionName() { … }` only provide an old style or no-info-about-input-parameters prototype for the function.  And need to take back "compiler knows it is a function that takes no arguments".  I'd say it nows nothing input parameters about that too.  My `_Generic` and pointer assignment testing was flawed.  Perhaps I'll post a Q/A in the future.  IAC, `SomeType FunctionName(void) { … }` remains better.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I believe we are (and always have been) 100% in agreement that the explicit `SomeType FunctionName(void) { … }` definition is preferred (and the `SomeType FunctionName(void);` declaration, too).

Comment: Just looked at the grammar rules in §6.7.6 Declarators. There's a rule `direct-declarator` with two relevant options: `direct-declarator ( parameter-type-list )` and `direct-declarator ( identifier-list-opt )`. That means that the empty parentheses version has an empty optional identifier-list. The `parameter-type-list` is not allowed to be empty. It supports the `, ...` at the end and that must follow at least one parameter-declaration — there'd need to be some juggling of the grammar rules to make the parameter-type-list optional instead of the identifier-list. It could be done (but hasn't).