# pthread_create function without arguments

Tags: c, arguments, pthreads

I'm trying to understand how `pthread_create` and `pthread_join` works. I thought that the third argument of `pthread_create` only allows functions with one argument of void*. I compiled the code below with gcc and it worked just fine. But why?

```
void *foo() {
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread_id;
    int par = 5;
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, foo, &par);
    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which gcc version ? It should say ` ....no known conversion from 'void *()' to 'void *(*)(void *)' for 3rd argument`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`void foo()`

means that the function foo can take any number of arguments of unknown type, while

`void foo(void *)`

means that the function foo takes a argument of type `void *`
That is why the program compiles, as your function can accept any type of arguments, including `void *`

The argument `void *` is a void pointer that has no associated data type with it. It can hold address of any type and can be typecasted to any type.

To find the difference between `foo()` and `foo(void *)` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/is-it-better-to-use-c-void-arguments-void-foovoid-or-not-void-foo)