# how do i randomly select an element in an array?

Tags: arrays, c, random

So I've been trying to do this for an embarrassingly long time now. First of all here is my (very bad) code:

```
char firstInfection() {            
     char cities[] = {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff"};            
     srand(time(NULL));            
     int randnum = rand() % 5;            
     char firstCity = cities[randnum];            
     return firstCity; 
}
```

I didn't include the preprocessor stuff but I'm also using string, math and time (obviously stdio and stdlib too)

Line 2 errors out here, saying: `error: too many initializers for ‘char []’` 
I'm not really sure what's going on here.

I'm having trouble understanding some of the things I need to do. I was told on tutorialspoint that I have to initialize random with line 3: `srand(time(NULL))`
I'm not sure why lol.

I tried shortening the names of the elements in `cities[]`

I'm not really sure what else to do try. I'm guessing that the whole thing is completely wrong but I really don't know.

Comment: you need `char* firstCity`. also this has undefined behavior as you are returning off the stack

Comment: you are not working with character literals correctly in C. in C, character literals require single-quotes (') instead of double quotes and must contain a single character. if you intended to work with "strings", so char-arrays, you should define and initialize your array as `char* cities[] = {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff"};`

Comment: it looks like the only difference here is the pointer... im not really sure how that fixes it but i'll still try that!

Comment: check out "strings" in C: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm, and array as pointer in C: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_to_an_array.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given by [@abelenky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71633106/17939455) it not that good as he/she is calling `srand()` function inside a function which is not `main()`. *NOTE: `srand()` should be called only once in any program within the `main()` function.*

##### Some Improvements:

- Instead to using bare `return 0;`, use `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`, which is defined in the header file `stdlib.h`.
- Data type `char` means a single character which is enclosed within single quotes `''`, use `char *` ([c-string](http://www.cs.kent.edu/%7Edurand/CS2/Notes/01_Intro/c2_stringCstyle.html)) to store multiple characters.
- Always use `size_t` to store indexes of any arrays, instead of `int`
- **Only `C`** If your function is not taking any arguments then write it like this `int func(void) { }`, here's [why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/693791/17939455).
- Instead of using bare `rand() % 5`, get the size of the array stored on stack memory using `sizeof()` operator
- Mark your local variable `cities` as `static` because you are returning it too.
- Your function `firstInfection()` should be declared with `static` linkage.
- You are calling `time()` function which is declared in `time.h` header file, so include that too

#### Final Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static const char *firstInfection(void)
{
    static const char *cities[] = {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff"};
    size_t rnd_index = rand() % (sizeof(cities) / sizeof(*cities));
    return cities[rnd_index];
}

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("%s\n", firstInfection());
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

##### Output:

```
[tushar@tushar-arch Desktop]$ ./main
aa
[tushar@tushar-arch Desktop]$ ./main
ee
[tushar@tushar-arch Desktop]$ ./main
cc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char* firstInfection() {            
     static const char* cities[] = {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff"};            
     srand(time(NULL));            
     int randnum = rand() % 6;  // Select value 0 to 5 (inclusive)            
     const char* firstCity = cities[randnum];            
     return firstCity; 
}

int main(void) {
    
    printf("Random String: %s\n", firstInfection());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thats still undefined behavior!

Comment: ohhh pointers xD 

im not really sure what the difference here is though? Like in what situation should I use a pointer and when shouldnt i?

Comment: the use of `char*` as type for the elements of the array is nothing more as C's way of referring to a multi-character string as there does not exist a thing such as a "string" in C. In C, strings are represented as an array of `char`'s. An array type can be referred to by its base pointer, which is why we can use `char*` instead of `char[]`

Comment: oh and also this solution errors out again.

ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
    4 |  char* cities[] = {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff"};

and it does this for every element in the array.