# Difference between void and non void functions

Tags: c, function, void

So I get that a void function won't return a value, while a int one for example will return an integer. So `void main(){}` doesnt return, but `int main(){return 0;}` will return.

My question is, what is the difference between these 3 functions. I know the first one wont return a value, the second one will return an integer. But how about the third one? I know it returns an integer because I've tested it, so what does that (void) does? Why is is there?
`void main(){}`
`int main(){return 0;};`
`int main(void){return 0;};`

I'm a begginer so sorry if it sounded confusing... Thanks in advance!!

(The question is about the programming language C)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/is-it-better-to-use-c-void-arguments-void-foovoid-or-not-void-foo answered here

Comment: `void main()` and `void main(void)` are wrong. The `main` function needs to return `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Between the parenthesis are the **parameters** to the function.

In a function definition, the proper way to designate a function that takes no parameters is to simply specify `void` for the parameter list.

An empty parameter list (in a definition) is also a way of saying the function takes no parameters, however this syntax is considered deprecated and should not be used in new programs.

Comment: Many implementations use a calling convention which is agnostic to the presence or absence of arguments beyond those specified.  On such implementations, a single `int dummyHandlerInt() { return 0; }` function could be used as a safe default value for function pointers of all types that return `int`, whose default behavior should be to return 0 without side effects.  The Standard would allow implementations to require the definition of a separate dummy function for every combination of argument types, since some calling conventions would require the existence of separate functions, ...

Comment: ...but many implementations allow programmers to avoid such needless verbosity.