# confusing error with qsort method

Tags: c

So, I have an array of string (name input), and I want to sort that array. I use something like this

```
int stringLen = sizeof(input)/sizeof(char *);
qsort(input, stringLen, sizeof(char *), myCompare);
```

However I get this confusing error:

> ```
> error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)(const char*, const char*)' to '__compar_fn_t {aka int (*)(const void*, const void*)}' [-fpermissive]
> ```
>
> In file included from srot13u.c:5:0:
>   /usr/include/stdlib.h:761:13: error:   initializing argument 4 of 'void qsort(void*, size_t, size_t, __compar_fn_t)' [-fpermissive]

Comment: What is `myCompare`? Is it `int myCompare(const char *, const char *)`? Because the error message suggests it expects `myCompare` to look like `int myCompare(const void *, const void *)`.

Comment: a compare method that I write. int myCompare(char const *a,char const *b). it will return 1 if a>b, 0 if a=b, -1 if a<b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your myCompare function has the signature:

```
int myCompare(const char*, const char*)
```

but

```
int myCompare(const void*, const void*)
```

is expected.

Just use

```
int myCompare(const void *a_, const void *b_) {
    const char *a = a_;
    const char *b = b_;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Huh, that's quite a complicated concept if you are not familiar to it. `void` is "nothing", the "unknown" type. Read http://stackoverflow.com/q/1043034/ for a better explanations. In C++ (or Java ...) you would use templates instead of an undefined type, but C does not have such a concept.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing an function taking two `char` pointers, but `qsort` wants one that takes `void` pointers. These two function pointer types are *not* compatible in C.

Change your comparison routine; the common setup is something like

```
static int strcmp_void(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return strcmp(a, b);  // the types *are* compatible in this expression
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `myCompare` like this:

```
int myCompare(const void* pa, const void* pb) {
   const char *a = (const char*)pa;
   const char *b = (const char*)pb;

   /* ... */
}
```