# what is the real meaning of 'void' in C#?

Tags: c#, null, structure, void, return-type

I was looking at definition for `void` type in C#. It's an empty structure that represents a no value.

But, what is exactly the difference between this structure and others. I mean If you define a method with return type of void and then you `return typeOf(void)` you will get an error.

It seems that C# have different behavior with this type.

There is a little documentation of what `void` really is. I mean what's going on under the hood. how can a value type structure refer to nothing ?

**UPDATE:**

I think that some of you guys didn't get the point of this question and this is why you marked it as duplicate. My question is. Void is an structure. OK ? .. Structures are value types. 
In the lowest possible stage what happens ? what void represents in memory? What is the difference between this structure and others while if you press F12 on void you see only an empty structure ? Where c# makes this difference ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: check this link..


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043034/what-does-void-mean-in-c-c-and-c

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: `void**` is very different to `void`.

Comment: I Still believe that it's not a duplicate question. My question is about the philosophy and theory. Of course that I know what void means. none of questions above are my answers. please refrain making such misundestandings

Answer (score 12):

The point is that a method with a `void` return type *does not return anything*. It doesn't return a value of type `void`; it has no return value at all.

You can't declare a method of that type; you can't declare a parameter to be `void`... it represents the absence of any value at all. The type [`System.Void`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.void.aspx) really only exists to facilitate reflection, where things like [`MethodInfo.ReturnType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.returntype.aspx) need to indicate that a method doesn't return anything.

There are many ways in which it would be useful if `void` *were* a real type, just as [`Unit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483472.aspx) is in F#. For example, we could then *just* have `Task<T>` instead of `Task<T>` and `Task`... effectively `Task` is `Task<void>`, but that's not valid...

Comment: I could probably try this when I get back to my computer.. but do `void` pointers work in unsafe C#?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: I think void pointers end up meaning something a bit different. I try to avoid pointers myself :) (But yes, they work.)

Answer (score 3):

It's actually [fairly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_type) [well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yah0tteb.aspx) [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It's a fundamental concept in [type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory), related to the [unit type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type).

In fact you can use `typeof(void)`, although there's not very much you can do with it. The reason why

```
public void foo() { return typeof(void); }
```

won't work is because the result of `typeof(void)` isn't an instance of the `void` type, it's an instance of the `Type` type. The proper way to write this, is simply

```
public void foo() { return; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Some languages has 2 different forms of subroutines. Procedures and Functions. The difference is that procdures are a sequence of operations. Functions are operations with a return statement.

In C# everything is a "function", so the void keyword just show, that it is not actually a function, because it has no return statement.

Answer (score 1):

> When used as the return type for a method, void specifies that the
>   method doesn't return a value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the word Void means none. where a Value is void it means it has no Value. in a method or function it means it doesen't have a return Type therefore your function doesent have to return anything to run

```
public static void TestRefType()
{
SampleRefType rt = new SampleRefType();
rt.value = 44;
ModifyObject(rt);
System.Console.WriteLine(rt.value);
}
```