# call a function in a std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have :

```
enum Screens
{
    INVENTORY,
    STUFF,
    CRAFTING,
    GAMESCREEN,
    NONE
};

typedef struct  s_action    
{
    s_action() : _screen(NONE), _compartment(NULL){};
    Screens     _screen;
    Compartment *_compartment;
}               s_action;

std::map<Screens, std::map<Screens, void (GestionClick::*)(s_action&, s_action&)> > _correlationTable;
```

What is the syntax in order to call a member function of GestionClick ?

Comment: `(gc.*_correlationTable[_screen1][_screen2])(s_action1, s_action2)`

Comment: I wouldn't call this a syntax question, it's more a basic understanding of accessing maps, and calling functions. Check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043034/what-does-void-mean-in-c-c-and-c

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Screens a;
Screens b;
(*_correlationTable[a][b])(action1, action2);
```

But I'm highly going to suggest that you use some `using` declarations (for readability) and `std::function` (and possibly `std::bind`) defined in the `<functional>` header instead (if you are using C++11):

```
using callback     = std::function<void(s_action&, s_action&)>;
using screens_map  = std::map<Screens, callback>;
std::map<Screens, std::map<Screens, screens_map> _correlationTable;
```