# What does (void)var actually do?

Tags: c, void, c89

Consider the following `main()`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return (0);
}
```

Upon compilation with `cc -Wall -Wextra`, warnings saying "unused parameter" get generated.

When I do not need to use a parameter in a function (for instance in a [signal handler function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling) that makes no use of its `int` parameter), I am used to doing the following:

```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      (void)argc;
      (void)argv;
      return (0);
  }
```

> (For that particular `main()`, I sometimes see other people do: `argv = argv - argc + argc`)

But **what does `(void)var` actually *do*?**

I understand that `(void)` is a cast, so I guess I am casting away the variable? What does the `var;` line (without the cast) do? Is it an empty assignment, an empty expression?

I would like to understand what is actually going on.

Comment: If expr has no lvalue and is not a function call, then `expr;` is a statement with no effect. It does nothing. Writing `(void) expr;` supresses the warning of a statement with no effect. Writing a statement with no effect involving `expr` in it silences warnings involved with not using `expr` in a function where `expr` appears in the parameter list.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's just a way of creating a 'harmless' reference to the variable. The compiler doesn't complain about an unused variable, because you did reference the value, and it doesn't complain that you didn't do anything with the value of the expression `var` because you explicitly cast it to void (nothing), indicating that you didn't care about the value.

I haven't seen this usage on variables before (because the compiler I use doesn't normally complain about unused function arguments,) but I see this used frequently to indicate to the compiler that you don't really care about the return value of a function. `printf(),` for example, returns a value, but 99% of C programmers don't know (or care) what it returns. To make some fussy compilers or lint tools not complain about an unused return value, you can cast the return value to void, to indicate that you know it's there, and you explicitly don't care about it.

Other than communicating your intent (that you don't care about this value) to the compiler, it doesn't actually *do* anything - it's just a hint to the compiler.

Answer (score 10):

```
  (void)argc;
  (void)argv;
```

If a function argument is not used, like in your program, then this is the idiomatic way of suppressing the warning of unused function argument issued by some compilers. Any decent compiler will not generate code with these statements.

It evaluates the argument but does nothing with it which has the effect for most compilers to not issue a warning. The `(void)` cast is used so the compiler would not produce another warning notifying that the value is not used.

Another popular way to suppress the warning is to do:

```
variable = variable;
```

Note that I know some compilers that will issue another warning in presence of:

```
(void) arg;
```

like "statement with no effect".

Comment: Many thanks! I did not know that other errors ("statement with no effect") could be raised with this technique. My school compiles our projects with `-Werror`, and I want an actual grade, haha!

Comment: For what it's worth, my company compiles with -Werror, too: it's painful when you first turn it on for a large project, but not too bad if you start out with it, and in the long run, the more warnings you turn on and leave on, the better your code - not only does the compiler find real problems for you, but programmers are forced to learn more about the language as they work out how to avoid certain warnings, and that helps them be better coders in the long run.

Comment: @JVMATL One of the issues with `-Werror` is in a Makefile it will typically exit the compilation process, while you may be interested to have a big picture with the dump of all the warnings.

Comment: @ouah if you use 'make -k' (-k == "keep going") you still get all (most of) your warnings. Unless you are using recursive makefiles.. :) (http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf)

Comment: @JVMATL but "keep going" would continue the process also for the other   (not compilation) errors which may not be the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

As other persons correctly noted, It just suppresses a compiler warning about unused variable in your code.
Btw, Win32 has defined `UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER` macro to reach this goal.
My suggestion to make something like that in your code:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
# define UNUSED(x) UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(x)
#else
# define UNUSED(x) (void) x
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

This may increase the code efficiency because the call of function dont need to load the registers for arguments.

Comment: Can you back up this claim by some data or by a citation?