# C#:: What is the difference between int main(){...} void main(){...} int main(void){...} void main(void){...}

Tags: c#, program-entry-point, void

I am new to programming
I am coding in C# and its kind of confusing.

What is the difference between these:
[image: Method signatures]

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I think you want to ask about difference of `main` method in C/C++. C# uses main method similar like Java has (without `void` argument): `static void Main()` or `static int Main()`.

Comment: Possible duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296163/why-is-the-type-of-the-main-function-in-c-and-c-left-to-the-user-to-define & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356510/int-main-vs-void-main-in-c.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- function uses to return an integer number

```
int main()
{
  return 1;
}
```

so if you call this function like this:

```
int x = main();
```

result of x will be "1"

2- void function does n't return any value

```
void main()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
```

so you can call this function like this:

```
void main();
```

this just execute "void main" function and would not return anything

Comment: That was very helpful, but what about the last 2?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to answer a question on a programming quiz. If you are struggling with this basic of a question, I would question your rationale in attempting such a test.

Nevertheless, when starting out, it's useful to understand that:

`int main(){...}` is a method that returns an integer.

`void main(){...}` is a method that does not return a value.

The latter two lines in your image are not valid method declarations, because `void` is placed as an input parameter, which is not a permitted usage of the `void` keyword.

If you desire to understand what the `void` keyword is really all about, you could start with [What does void mean in C, C++, and C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043034/what-does-void-mean-in-c-c-and-c) and [Void (C# Reference) (Microsoft)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/void).