# Use of 'void' in a function parameter

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [C void arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/c-void-arguments)

I just started with C and I can't find answer to this...

Is there any difference between

```
int foo() { }

int foo(void) { }
```

Which should I prefer and why?

Note that this question also goes for: `int main`. Should it be: `int main` or `int main(void)` when I don't want any command-line arguments?

Comment: Similar questions: [Is there a difference between foo(void) and foo() in C++ or C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032/is-there-a-difference-between-foovoid-and-foo-in-c-or-c) and [C void arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693788/c-void-arguments)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The two canonical forms of `main` are, according to the standard (see C99 section 5.1.2.2.2 "Program startup"):

```
int main (void);
int main (int argc, char *argv[]); // or equivalent such as char **argv
```

Others are specifically allowed but those are the required ones.

As to the preferred form between `fn(void)` and `fn()`, I prefer the former since I like to explicitly state that there are no parameters.

There is also a subtle difference. C99 section 6.7.5.3 "Function declarators", paragraph 10, states:

> The special case of an unnamed parameter of type void as the only item in the list
>   specifies that the function has no parameters.

Paragraph 14 of that same section shows the only difference:

> An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of the function. An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters. The empty list in a function declarator that is not part of a definition of that function specifies that no information about the number or types of the parameters is supplied.

In other words, it means the same as `void` in the function definition but does *not* mean that in a standalone declarator (i.e., the prototype). `int fn();` means that no information on the parameters is yet known but `int fn(void);` means there are no parameters.

That means that:

```
int fn();
int fn (int x) { return x; }
int main (void) { return fn(0); }
```

is valid but:

```
int fn(void);
int fn (int x) { return x; }
int main (void) { return fn(0); }
```

is not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where can I download the standard from just for reference? I seem to be hitting paid links while searching.

Comment: The best you can do for free is probably at the bottom of the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99 or a direct link http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf - this is the draft of C99 + TCs 1, 2 and 3. It's pretty dry reading though :-)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [paxdiablo's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075530/use-of-void-in-a-function-parameter/5075577#5075577), which covers the C language and thus the OP's question, it may be worth noting that "void style" is considered bad practice in C++, at least by Bjarne Stroustrup.

The reasons why are purely style-related, but the use of void as function parameter was actually banned from C++ in the early days before ISO standardization. The void syntax was eventually allowed though, to provide compatibility with C.

So to sum this up:

- In C programs, use `f(void)` because it enforces stricter typing (rational argument)
- In C++ programs, use `f()`, or you will upset various C++ gurus (irrational argument)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, no difference.  Some old C compilers would complain about the absence of void in that case, but there is no reason to do that in modern C or C++.

Comment: Which one should I prefer? Surely there has to be the one everyone uses! I even downloaded the `coreutils` source code to check, but every `main` has a command line argument!

Comment: Not true.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416345/is-fvoid-deprecated-in-modern-c-and-c

Answer (score 0):

There are no differences between the statements.

If you write `int main(void)`, this statement tells the compiler that `main` does not contain any arguments.

And similarly, in case of `main()` or `int main()`, again the compiler understands `main` does not contain any arguments.  But, in the first case, you are forcefully telling the compiler, while in the second statement the compiler understand automatically.

Comment: Not true.  foo(void) means the function takes zero arguments.  foo() means the function takes an unknown number of arguments.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416345/is-fvoid-deprecated-in-modern-c-and-c

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you use command-line arguments, the signature of main() includes the parameters that would allow command-line arguments to be accessed.

View the signature as a contract with the caller, not an announcement of what the implementation actually uses.

Answer (score -1):

They are the same, but preferred one is `int foo() { }`

Comment: Why is that preferred? It allows you to pass an object of type Rubbish_t to the function foo().

Comment: They are not the same to a C compiler.  foo(void) means the function takes zero arguments.  foo() means the function takes an unknown number of arguments.