# Objective-C blocks variable parameters mismatch definition

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Why does the compiler allow the line below without errors or warnings?  It seems that it should complain about the parameter mismatch in the "onSuccess" declaration and the definition.

I'm using Xcode 4.6 (LLVM 4.2)

```
void (^onSuccess)() = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
};
```

Comment: Shows us the original typedef.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work just like C function declarations. To Quote from the C99 standard:

> (6.7.5.3/14) [...]The empty list in a function declarator that is not part of a definition of that function specifies that no information about the number or types of the parameters is supplied.[...]

Meaning, you can **declare** a function (and as it seems also a block) and not provide any information about parameters.

Comment: Nearly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950642/why-does-a-function-with-no-parameters-compared-to-the-actual-function-definiti

Comment: Also nearly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075530/use-of-void-in-function-parameter