# Using void in functions without parameter?

Tags: c++, function, methods, void

In C++ using `void` in a function with no parameter, for example:

```
class WinMessage
{
public:
    BOOL Translate(void);
};
```

is redundant, you might as well just write  `Translate();`.

I, myself generally include it since it's a bit helpful when code-completion supporting IDEs display a `void`, since it ensures me that the function takes definitely no parameter.

My question is, Is adding `void` to parameter-less functions a good practice? Should it be encouraged in modern code?

Comment: @awoodland: "I got a hangover from C." Mhmm. Seems fitting. `:)`

Comment: Here is the Link that might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412274/why-add-void-to-method-parameter-list

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In C++

```
void f(void);
```

is identical to:

```
void f();
```

The fact that the first style can still be legally written can be attributed to C.
n3290 § C.1.7 (C++ and ISO C compatibility) states:

> **Change**: In C++, a function declared with an empty parameter list takes
>   no arguments.
>
> In C, an empty parameter list means that the number and
>   type of the function arguments are unknown.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> int f(); // means int f(void) in C++
>          // int f( unknown ) in C
> ```

In C, it makes sense to avoid that undesirable "unknown" meaning. In C++, it's superfluous.

Short answer: in C++ it's a hangover from too much C programming. That puts it in the "don't do it unless you really have to" bracket for C++ in my view.

Comment: Is there any equivalent to C's `int f()` in C++? Should I use `external "C"` for this use case?

Comment: @Spidey why would you want to do that? It's undefined behaviour if you get it wrong and a legacy hangover from early C days to reduce compiler/linker complexity. In C++11 variadic templates are a safe, modern feature though but not a direct equivalent.

Comment: I've used it as a type for a function pointer array. We exchanged array pointers between client and dll code, and thus avoid the overhead of calling dll functions constantly.

Comment: @Spidey If you want platform specific then I'd just make it an array of `FARPROC` and cast for calls.

Comment: I can't find after a fast and basic search if FARPROC is defined by the standard. I'm using C89 in embedded devices, I don't think I can depend on FARPROC being defined. By the way, what is FARPROC definition? I bet it is `int f()` or `void *f()`.

Comment: In windef.h: typedef int (FAR WINAPI *FARPROC)();
http://forums.devarticles.com/showpost.php?p=99993&postcount=2

Comment: FARPROC is windows specific, but if you're relying on undefined behaviour as an optimisation for windows specific case then that's an upgrade. (Happy to chat more in: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec before this goes any further off-topic)

Answer (score 6):

I see absolutely no reason for this. IDEs will just complete the function call with an empty argument list, and 4 characters less.

Personally I believe this is making the already verbose C++ even more verbose. There's no version of the language I'm aware of that requires the use of `void` here.

Comment: If you think C++ is verbose, try Java. `:)`

Comment: Depends on what Java version you are talking about and also on what kind of work you do. Post Java 8, the language is not as verbose, and C++ metaprogramming can be quite tangled (to put it mindly.)

PS. I work with both languages professionally. They both can be verbose depending what you are doing with either.

Answer (score 5):

I think it will only help in backward compatibility with older C code, otherwise it is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

I *feel like* no. Reasons:

- A lot more code out there has the `BOOL Translate()` form, so others reading your code will be more comfortable and productive with it.
- Having less on the screen (especially something redundant like this) means less thinking for somebody reading your code.
- Sometimes people, who didn't program in C in 1988, ask "What does `foo(void)` mean?"

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side note. Another reason for not including the void is that software, like starUML,  that can read code and generate class diagrams, read the void as a parameter. Even though this may be a flaw in the UML generating software, it is still annoying to have to go back and remove the "void"s if you want to have clean diagrams

Comment: send a bugreport to the starUML maintainers.