# Determining when to use a function on certain classes if they inherit an abstract base class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

So presume I have a base class `Object` and an abstract base class `Collidable`.  (`Object` containing position information and such and `Collidable` containing `virtual void Collide(Object object) = 0`. There will then be child classes that inherit `Object`, but only certain ones will also inherit `Collidable`.  So my question is, if one of those collidable child classes were to check through a list of `Object` inherited classes, how might it determine if they also inherit `Collidable` so that they collide with each other and not with objects that aren't collidable?

(To give a more visual look at my question)

```
class Object
{
protected:
    Position myPosition;

public:
    Object(void);
    ~Object(void);
}

class Collidable
{
protected:
/* ... */

public:
    virtual void Collide(Object& object) = 0;

    Collidable(void);
    ~Collidable(void);
}

class Grass : public Object
{
private:
/* ... */

public:

    Grass(void);
    ~Grass(void);
}

class Wall : public Object, public Collidable
{
private:
/* ... */

public:
    virtual void Collide(Object& object) { /* Collide logic */ }

    Wall(void);
    ~Wall(void);
}

class Monster : public Object, public Collidable
{
private:
/* ... */

public:
    virtual void Collide(Object& object) { /* Collide logic */ }

    Monster(void);
    ~Monster(void);
}

int main()
{
    Monster creature;
    Object* objects[] = { /* list of Grass, Wall, and Monster classes */ };

    for(int i = 0, i < objects.size(); i++)
    {
        //Logical error: not every object is collidable
        creature.Collide(&objects[i]);
    }
}
```

So here, I have a list of `Wall` `Monster` and `Grass` classes, but `Grass` is not collidable, however, let's say that it needs to stay in the array with the other classes.  How might I determine if the class in the array is `Collidable`?

( I do apologize if I am somehow way off key here, but I have been researching and studying a bunch of object oriented things recently so I am still in my learning phase here. )

Comment: probably a terrible suggestion, but you could add a isCollidable() virtual method to Object, which has a default implementation that returns false.  Then, on your subclasses that also inherit Collidable, override isCollidable() to return true.  Then you can just check at runtime.

Comment: I recommend looking up how to implement Component systems. Some helpful links are: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75721/how-should-an-object-that-uses-composition-set-its-composed-components and http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html and http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/

Comment: @bstar55 - That isn't a horrible idea, it is a much better idea than what I am trying to do in this question of mine.

Comment: @Casey - Thanks for the links, I will certainly look them over, I will take all the help I can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Note: Some advice especially if you're in the learning phase - if you make sure your example code compiles some baseline, it makes it easier for people to adapt a working version for the part you are asking about.  The compiler warnings are also instructive so you can find out about mistakes ahead of time... for instance you're missing a virtual destructor on Object.  It can be a distraction if we don't know whether you know why that's bad or not.)*

---

You're trying to encode attributes into objects by virtue of what classes they inherit from, and then check for those attributes at *runtime*.

It is technically possible to use [Run-Time-Type-Information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information), use a `dynamic_cast<>` and notice when it returns a null pointer.

```
Grass grass;
cout << dynamic_cast<Collidable *>(&grass) << "\n";

Monster monster;
cout << dynamic_cast<Collidable *>(&monster) << "\n";
```

When I run that I get:

```
0
0xbfabb10c
```

So the grass could be cast, and the monster could not.  This reduced case produces a compiler warning as well:

> warning: dynamic_cast of ‘Grass grass’ to ‘class Collidable*’ can never succeed [enabled by default]

But this is not really the intent of the C++ methodology.  It's better to think along the lines suggested by @bstar55 and having a virtual `isCollidable()` on all Objects, with some returning false.  Or even to consider if there's a difference between an object isn't "collidable" and one that has a collision test that always fails.  It depends on the design of your system.

Instead of trying to navigate the class hierarchy at run-time, a better focus is to think about using inheritance or "traits" when doing **compile-time** work.  That's the real beauty of it.  But it's a deep topic.  I'll just point you to a couple bits like [std::is_base_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) and [a list of other type traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types).

Comment: Thanks for the note, I will keep that in mind next time, I was just in a bit of a rush today and couldn't really think everything through like I normally try to do.  This is really helpful and thank you for directing me towards more proper habits.  There is still a lot about OOP that I don't seem to know still.  And no, I didn't know about the virtual destructor at all.  Thank you.

Comment: @Uulamock No problem.  These blog entries of mine might be helpful, at least I would have found them so: [Modern C++ or Modern Art](http://blog.hostilefork.com/modern-cpp-or-modern-art/), and possibly this one: [IOstreams re-examined](http://blog.hostilefork.com/iostreams-reexamined/)

Comment: I will certainly read over these when I get the chance, thanks for helping me.  This kind of information truly helps me out a ton.

Answer (score 1):

You could [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to determine whether `object` is convertible to `Collidable` like the example below:

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<Object*> objects{ new Monster(), new Wall(), new Grass() };

  for (auto i : objects){
    if (dynamic_cast<Collidable*>(i)) dynamic_cast<Collidable*>(i)->Collide();
  }
}
```

### [Display](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48ddb362ebd6de42)

### Suggestions:

1. `foo(void)` [is deprecated in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416345/is-fvoid-deprecated-in-modern-c-and-c), it's a remnant from C.
2. When use inheritance you have to make [the destructor of base classes `virtual`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors) to assure that destructors are called in correct order.
3. Don't use C raw arrays instead use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).
4. Unlike the example above, don't use raw pointers but rather smart pointers like [`shared_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/).