# Does specifying the use of void in the declaration of a function that takes no arguments address The Most Vexing Parse?

Tags: c++, void, kernighan-and-ritchie, most-vexing-parse

Is the Most Vexing Parse rooted in the ambiguity about whether or not to use `void` as the parameter of a function declaration that takes no arguments?

As an example, the following code compiles without error, and runs fine, on both the g++ (v7.2.1) and Xcode (Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)) compilers.

```
#include <iostream>

int asdf(void);
int asdf(int a) {
    return a;
}
int main() {
    std::cout << asdf(6) << std::endl; //-> 6
    return 0;
}
```

This goes all the way back to the ANSI-C standard and before, where an empty parameter list indicated an arbitrary number of arguments. It haunts us today with backward-compatibility in the compilers, that seem to be a bit confused about the issue. Should the above not at least generate a warning, if not throw an error?

Here I had an epiphany (or perhaps a pipe dream!). Could it be that The Most Vexing Parse is rooted in the ambiguity about the use of `void` in an empty function declaration list?

Another example, Referencing the following Wikipedia example:

```
class Timer {
 public:
  Timer();
};

class TimeKeeper {
 public:
  TimeKeeper(const Timer& t);

  int get_time();
};

int main() {
  TimeKeeper time_keeper(Timer());
  return time_keeper.get_time();
}
```

> The line
>
> ```
> TimeKeeper time_keeper(Timer());
> ```
>
> is seemingly ambiguous, since it could be interpreted either as
>
> - a variable definition for variable time_keeper of class TimeKeeper, initialized with an anonymous instance of class Timer or
> - a function declaration for a function time_keeper which returns an object of type TimeKeeper and has a single (unnamed) parameter which
>     is a pointer to function returning type Timer (and taking no input).
>     (See Function object#In C and C++)

REFERENCE:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Now, if we specify that `void` must be used when declaring a function with no variables, does this not remove (not hackishly, fundamentally remove!) the ambiguity? The line in question would then become the following, leaving no doubt that it is a function declaration:

```
int main() {
  TimeKeeper time_keeper(Timer(void));
  return time_keeper.get_time();
}
```

This goes all the way back to KnR, where this issue is discussed:

> Since the specialized versions of getline and copy have no arguments,
>   logic would suggest that their prototypes at the beginning of the file
>   should be `getline()` and `copy()`. But for compatibility with
>   older C programs the standard takes an empty list as an old-style
>   declaration, and turns off all argument list checking; the word
>   `void` must be used for an explicitly empty list.
>   [Kernighan & Richie, the C programming language, 1988, Pgs 32-33]

and..

> The special meaning of the empty argument list is intended to permit
>   older C programs to compile with new compilers. But it's a bad idea to
>   use it with new programs. If the function takes arguments, declare
>   them; if it takes no arguments, use void [ibid, Pg. 73]

Reference:
[is f(void) deprecated in modern C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416345/is-fvoid-deprecated-in-modern-c-and-c)

Comment: "Should the above not generate a warning, if not throw an error?" No - why would you think it should? That code declares two functions, provides a definition for one of them, and calls that one.

Comment: The most vexing parse is how do you separate `foo bar();` from a function named `bar` returning a `foo` to a variable of type `foo` named `bar` that is default constructed.

Comment: @latedeveloper 2, Because of the argument mismatch between the function declaration and definition; specifically, the declaration specifies ``void`` arguments, while the definition specifies an integer argument.

Comment: @kmiklas The declaration and definition refer to two different functions.

Comment: @kmiklas: Are you asking if we could fix the most-vexing-parse by breaking *tons of existing C++ code*? If so, the answer is "sure we can".

Comment: @kmiklas it is not as definition of the same function as the declaration, you declare two separate functions, one taking no arguments, and one taking one argument. A key difference from C.

Comment: The C++ committee chose the solution of having `foo bar{};` being a variable, and keep `foo bar();` as the function declaration it has always been.

Comment: @NathanOliver - `foo bar();` is **not** the most vexing parse (see the link in the question). It's a function declaration, nothing more. People often confuse it with object creation, but that's not a parsing issue. The most vexing parse is far more vexing.

Answer (score 2):

A function definition is also a declaration.  That means when you have

```
int asdf(void);
int asdf(int a) {
    return a;
}
```

You have declared two version of `asdf`, one taking an `int` and one taking nothing.  You then go on to use the `int` version when you use

```
std::cout << asdf(6) << std::endl; //-> 6
```

There is nothing wrong with that since the `int` version is defined.

What would be an issue would be if you try to use

```
asdf();
```

When you do that since it has be declared but not defined you should get an

> undefined reference to `asdf()'

Since there is no definition.  This has nothing to do with the most vexing parse but just the difference between function declarations and definitions.

Comment: Ah, because the argument list is different, the function signature is different, and the call ``asdf(6)`` will match ``int asdf(int a) {``, correct?

Comment: @kmiklas Yes.  You have overloaded the function.  You just have not provided a definition for the `void` overload.

Comment: Thx. I got tangled up this business of rooting out a solution to The Most Vexing Parse, and missed the forest through the trees.

Answer (score 2):

Your proposal would not completely remove the ambiguity.

Consider:

```
#include <string>

struct Foo { ... };

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Foo bar(std::string(argv[1]));
}
```

This looks like it could be declaring a local variable `bar` of type `Foo`, passing a `std::string` to its constructor.

But what it actually means is:

```
Foo bar(std::string *argv);
```

I.e. declare `bar` as a function taking an argument of type "pointer to `std::string`" and returning a `Foo`.

This example can't be fixed by adding `void`.