# what does a c compiler do when doesn't find the matching function

Tags: c, function, c99

Consider the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int f()
{
        printf(" hey ");
        return 5;
}
int main()
{
        printf("hello there %d",f(4,5));
        f(4,5);
        return 0;
}
```

I expected something like too many arguments to function ‘int f()’  but it gives an output even in strict C99 compilation. why is [this](http://www.ideone.com/9K9ON) behavior?
But it seems like a C++ compiler gives an error.

Comment: A decent compiler will issue a warning, if the definition of `f` is in the same file as the function that calls it. However, if only the declaration has been seen, the code would have been legal.

Comment: a decent compiler in the sense?? the standard gcc didn't throw any error?

Comment: @Lindydancer:  The code is legal.  `int f()` declares f to take any arguments you like.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032/is-there-a-difference-between-foovoid-and-foo-in-c-or-c

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf
6.7.5.3 Function declarators

Comment: @JeremyP: 6.5.2.2.6: "If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype[...]. If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the behavior is undefined." In this case, when the compiler compiles `main` is sees the *definition* of `f`, and can conclude that there is a mismatch and warn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C is much less strict than C++ in some regards.

A function signature `f()` in C++ means a function without arguments, and a conforming compiler must enforce this. In C, by contrast, the behaviour is unspecified and compilers are not required to diagnose if a function is called with arguments even though it was defined without parameters. In practice, modern compilers should at least warn about the invalid usage.

Furthermore, in function prototype *declarations* (without definition) in C, empty parentheses mean that the parameters are *unspecified*. It can subsequently be defined with any number of arguments.

To prevent this, use the following prototype<sup>ISO/IEC 9899 6.7.6.3/10</sup>:

```
int f(void)
```

Comment: Right.  More precisely, calling it with the wrong number and/or type(s) of arguments needn't be diagnosed by the compiler.  The behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Konrad wrote, C will also implicitly declare functions for you. For example:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int* p = malloc(sizeof(int));
  return 0;
}
```

will compile (maybe with a warning) without a `#include <stdlib.h>` that contains the declaration.

Comment: Implicit function definitions are illegal in C99.  Your compiler should *at least* give you a warning.

Comment: @JeremyP gcc -std=c99 -c program.c only gave me a warning? Are yousure its illegal?

Comment: @sashang: the standard requires that ill-formed code is diagnosed, not that it fails to compile. A warning is a diagnostic. Implementations are permitted to compile it with whatever behavior the implementation likes.

Comment: C99 doesn't require a warning for the code in the question.  The *definition* of `f` provides an old-style declaration: `int f()`, which tells the compiler that `f` is a function returning int, but not how many arguments it expects.  C99 requires visible declarations for called functions; it doesn't (unfortunately IMHO) require those declarations to be prototypes.  (Even the C201X draft doesn't remove old-style function declarations and definitions.)

Comment: As for the code in this answer, it's a constraint violation in both C90 and C99, but for different reasons.  In C90, the call to `malloc` creates an implicit declaration: `int malloc(size_t);`.  There's no implicit conversion from `int` to `int*`.  In C99, the call requires a diagnostic because there's no visible declaration.