# Difference between `foo()` and `foo(void)`

Tags: java, methods

In Java, is there any difference between this two function declarations?

```
public void foo() {/*...*/}

public void foo(void) {/*...*/}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032/is-there-a-difference-between-foovoid-and-foo-in-c-or-c/51080#51080) you can find the answear to this question but for **C/C++**. In these languages it makes totally sense the existance of both declaration styles.

But what is the point of this in **Java** ?

Comment: What makes you think this compiles?

Comment: @KirkWoll sadly, my teacher...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The latter declaration illegal in Java. You can't declare a method like that. You should get an error like this:

```
Test.java:8: error: <identifier> expected
    public void foo(void) {/*...*/}
                        ^
1 error
```

So not only is there no point - you simply won't find valid code which attempts to use this style.

Comment: God is roaming freely in java.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
public void foo(Void v) {/*...*/}
```