# What's the difference between Void and no parameter?

Tags: java, void

I have a class which defines two overloaded methods

```
public void handle(Void e) 

protected void handle()
```

Obviously they are different, especially `handle(Void e)` is `public`.

What's the difference between those two?

How to call the first method? I am using `handle(null)` - is this correct?

Comment: Based on parameter and access you can call, if handle(), it will call second method and handle(null) or handle(null), it will call first one

Comment: @VinitPrajapati.. You cannot instantiate `Void`

Comment: @RohitJain Corrected comment

Comment: Exact duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217436/difference-between-foo-and-foovoid

Comment: it is different I think

Comment: yes this is correct. you can only call `public void handle(Void e)` using a `handle(null)` call

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The first function is a function of a single argument, which must be provided and can only validly take the value `null`. Any value other than null will not compile. The second function doesn't take any argument and passing `null` to it would not compile.

Comment: any purpose to use Void as parameter?

Comment: No, as Bohemian says it exists to be able to represent the return value of a void method for purposes of reflection.

Comment: So, what is a specific use case for using a `Void` parameter of a function?

Answer (score 70):

`Void` is a special class usually used only for reflection - its primary use is to represent the return type of a void method. From the [javadoc for `Void`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html):

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.

Because the `Void` class can not be instantiated, the only value you can pass to a method with a `Void` type parameter, such as `handle(Void e)`, is `null`.

That's the official version of events, but for those who are interested, despite claims to the contrary in the javadoc of `Void`, you *can* actually instantiate an instance of `Void`:

```
Constructor<Void> c = Void.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
c.setAccessible(true);
Void v = c.newInstance(); // Hello sailor!
```

That said, I have seen `Void` "usefully" used as a generic parameter type when you want to indicate that the type is being "ignored", for example:

```
Callable<Void> ignoreResult = new Callable<Void> () {
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        // do something
        return null; // only possible value for a Void type
    }
}
```

`Callable`'s generic parameter is the return type, so when `Void` is used like this, it's a clear signal to readers of the code that the returned value is not important, even though the use of the `Callable` interface is required, for example if using the `Executor` framework.

Comment: It does not mean "don't care about the type" it means "I want to return nothing but generics do not support `void` since it is not a class so I use `Void` instead".

Comment: +1 I believe you can instantiate an instance of `Void` by Reflection.

Comment: @Adam this may sound like a strange request, but would you Ming accepting another answer?  The reason is I would get a special "hat" if one of my answers outscores the accepted one. It would be a nice Xmas present :) - Thanks

Comment: @Adam that should have been *mind*, not Ming :) That's iPhone's auto correction crapnology for you... :/

Comment: I have used `Void`, perhaps *unconventionally*, to resolve conflicts when expanding methods with more parameters (don't ask why). If `methodA(String)` needs to be expanded to `methodA(String, String)`, but `methodA(String, String)` already exists with a different meaning, I'd expand the first method as `methodA(String, Void, String)` (and call it as `methodA(strA, (Void)null, strB)`). Sure I can make it `methodB(String, String)`, but sometimes, not. (Again, don't ask why!)

Comment: @ADTC I would just make it `methodB(String, String)`

Comment: I would too, but sometimes can't. Don't ask why. `:/` (Perks of working on large corporate systems.)

Comment: Helpful answer. Although, early in the Answer you say "usually used only for reflection" and then later you say "usefully used as a generic parameter type". I have also seen this latter use - doesn't this contradict what you say earlier about it being used only for reflection (albeit qualified as usually)?

Answer (score 15):

Consider the API to `AsyncTask<T1, T2, T3>` from [the Android system](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), which provides three hooks:

```
class AsyncTask<S, T, V> {
  void doInBackground(S...);
  void onProgressUpdate(T...);
  void onPostExecute(V);
}
```

When you extend the generic type `AsyncTask<T1, T2, T3>` you may not be interested in using parameters for the *progress* and *result* hooks, so your implementation will look like:

```
class HTTPDownloader extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {
  void doInBackground(URL... urls) {}
  void onProgressUpdate(Void... unused) {}
  void onPostExecute(Void unused) {}
}
```

and you can invoke these methods with a `null` parameter, since `Void` can't be instantiated.

Comment: The `Void ...` is needed to preserve argument count so `onProgressUpdate` properly overrides the same method in the parent (since in java, not passing an argument to this would cause it to become a new function rather than an override).

Answer (score 6):

If `Void` isn't actually an instantiation of a type parameter (where it obviously makes sense), there is also sense in declaring a `handle(Void)` if your `handle` method is subject to an extralinguistic contract that says that the object that wants to participate in a certain protocol must implement a **one-argument handle method**, regardless of the actual argument type. Now, there may be a special-case implementation that can't handle anything but `null` so it makes sense to declare `handle(Void)` for such an implementation.