# Illegal start of type for class member functions

Tags: java

Why is Netbeans returning "illegal start of type for" connect, disconnect and getDataFromSerialPort member functions below.

What's wrong with those lines?

```
import jssc.SerialPortEvent;
import jssc.SerialPortEventListener;
import jssc.SerialPortException;
import jssc.SerialPort;

public class SerialComm implements SerialPortEventListener {
    private SerialPort serialPort;

    public void connect(void)
    {

    }

    public void disconnect(void)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you think the keyword `void` does in parameter lists? Why do you think so?

Comment: you mustn't use `(void)`, but you can write `()`

Comment: What is the reason for so many downVotes???  I did my research on it and what I found is that many people were trying to put if statements and etc outside the member functions.  Those post actually got upvoted quite a bit, so why would my question be downVoted.  I come from a embedded c language background and putting void in the parameter list is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Andrew Tobiliko: Thanks for the info.

Comment: So your reason for thinking that Java supports `void` as a parameter type (even without a variable name) is that C supports it? Please add that to the question.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis At the time, I had no idea that the void type was the problem, so there wouldn't be any reason to add it to the question.  I would have not asked the question or even had a problem if I had thought void was the problem.

Comment: This was probably downvoted because you did not provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the problem. The less code there is, the easier it is to spot mistakes, not only for you but also for people who want to help you.

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks for the infor, but I thought the amount of code I posted wasn't too much.  Actually, at the time I didn't know what was causing the issue, so I posted the whole class, which is pretty minimal.  Also, In my I also mentioned which lines were having the issue.  For this situation, I think it would be pretty easy for an experienced java person to immediately spot the issue.

Comment: Agreed but since you know which lines are causing the issue, why not extract one of the lines in question and post that?

Answer (score 1):

Take the void out of the parameters and just use ().

```
 public byte[] getDataFromSerialPort()
{
    return new byte[] {1,2,3};
}
```

Check out this other question [Difference between `foo()` and `foo(void)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217436/difference-between-foo-and-foovoid)

Hope it helps!

Comment: @user1164199 no problem! If this helped answer your question, please mark as the answer! =)