# int foo (int argc, ...) vs int foo() vs int foo(void) in C

Tags: c, arguments, argument-passing

So today I figured (for the first time admittedly) that `int foo()` is in fact different from `int foo(void)` in that the first one allows *any* number of inputs and the second one allows *zero*.

Does `int foo()` simply ignore any given inputs? If so, what's the point of allowing this form of function? If not, how can you access them and how is this different from having a variable argument list (e.g.  something like `int foo (int argc, ...)`)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032/is-there-a-difference-between-foovoid-and-foo-in-c-or-c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to understanding this is understanding the call stack.  What happens when you call a function in C (with the standard x86 ABI — other platforms may vary) is that the caller pushes all of the arguments, in reverse order, onto the stack before calling the callee.  Then, the callee can read as many of those arguments as it wants.  If you use foo(void), obviously you won't read any.  If you use foo(int), you'll be able to read one word into the stack below your current frame.

Using foo() (with no args specified) means that the compiler won't care to check the arguments you pass to foo.  Anything goes; there's no contract.  This can be useful if foo has two different implementations that take different types as arguments, and I want to be able to switch them out programmatically.  (It's also sometimes useful when writing functions in assembler, where you can handle the stack and arguments yourself.)  But remember that the compiler is not going to do any type-checking for you, so you have to be very careful.

This is different from foo(int, ...), since in that case, the function actually has a way to access all of the arguments (using varargs).  There's no reason ever to actually *define* a function with foo(), since it's basically equivalent to foo(void).  foo() is only useful for *declarations*.

Comment: The only thing I'd add to the first paragraph is that the caller then pops (well... increments esp) the arguments off the stack, not the callee. This is important, as it wouldn't work with callee cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

First, take `int foo()`.  This form is a function declaration that does not provide a *prototype* - that is, it doesn't specify the number and types of its arguments.  It is an archaic form of function declaration - it's how functions were originally declared in pre-ANSI C.  Such a function however does *have* a fixed number and type of arguments - it's just that the declaration doesn't tell the compiler what it is, so you are responsible for getting it right where you call the function.  You declare such a function with arguments like so:

```
int foo(a, b)
    int a;
    char *b;
{
    return a + strlen(b);
}
```

This form of function declaration is now obsolete.

`int foo(void)` is a modern declaration that provides a prototype; it declares a function that takes no arguments.  `int foo(int argc, ...)` also provides a prototype; it declares a function that has one fixed integer argument and a variable argument list.

Answer (score 0):

In standard conform C, you have to use `int foo(void)` if the function does not accept any parameters.

I guess it is compiler dependant what happens, when you pass arguments to a function with empty braces. But I don't think there is a way to access these parameters.

As for main, the only standard conform (pure c) ways to write them are either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` (or char *argv[] which is the same).

Comment: After looking it up in the standard, it seems that empty braces also declare a function without parameters. It is generally good convention to write (void) to explicitly state that you don't expect any parameters.

If you have further questions like this, it is always a good idea to read what the standard says (and your implementations documentation, i.e., gcc, glibc...)
You can find drafts of the standards for free online.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in C++ the two forms are equivalent and they both declare a function that takes no arguments. If you try to call the function and pass in an argument, the compile will give an error.

On the other hand, C and Objective-C both treat the two forms differently. In these languages the first form declares a function that takes an unknown number of arguments, whereas the second form declares a function that takes no arguments at all. So, in C the following is valid code:

```
int foo() {
  return 5;
}
int main() {
  return foo(1, 2, 3);
}
```

The compiler doesn't complain, and the code runs fine (a C++ compiler would give an error on this same code).

Generally what you want in C and Objective-C is to use the second form and include the explicit void to indicate that the function should take no arguments. However, it's more common in C++ to use the first form because it's equivalent and shorter.