# What's the use case of foo() meaning foo has an unknown amount of arguments?

Tags: c, syntax, c99, function-prototypes

So I was recently reading a bit on Hacker News about function pointers and was enlightened to the fact that `void foo()` and `void foo(void)` are NOT equivalent prototypes. So, I set about ensuring that this is actually true:

```
int foo()
{
  return 0;
}
int main()
{
  return foo(1,2,3,4);
}
```

Sure enough, this code compiles without even so much as a warning.. where as this code will throw an error:

```
int foo(void)
{
  return 0;
}
int main()
{
  return foo(1,2,3,4);
}
```

This seems very error prone. I also thought that `...` for "any amount of arguments", such as in `printf`'s signature

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

Was this also true in C89 or K&R? Can anyone give insight into the use case for this "feature"?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784467/int-foo-int-argc-vs-int-foo-vs-int-foovoid-in-c

Comment: @ScottyBauer - good find.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a "feature", per se.  It's just the way the language used to be back in the beginning, so the syntax has lived on to keep old code working.  The addition of `void` made it possible to have functions that explicitly took no arguments, for example.

The use of the `...` indicates a variadic function, which is subtly different from a function that just takes an arbitrary number of arguments, though.  Using the `...` requires the use of `stdarg.h` macros, but just having a function declared with `()` doesn't.