# C++: Difference between contructor() and constructor(void)

Tags: c++

I have noticed that when I create a new C++ class in Visual Studio, it writes down `Foo(void)` and `~Foo(void)` as constructor and destructor templates instead of `Foo()` and `~Foo()`. However, both versions seem to work. Is there a difference between both or does it not matter at all which version I use?

Comment: Someone already respond =)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032/is-there-a-difference-between-foovoid-and-foo-in-c-or-c

Comment: This didn't show up in my search results because it is related to functions in general. I only saw it with constructors and destructors only until now.

Comment: Don't worry, it's not an accusation that you should've searched better. :) Your question was fine.

Comment: Someone gave me a downvote though ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, both are technically the same, as in "a function that takes no arguments"

For more info:

In C, however, Foo(void) is "a function that takes no arguments", but Foo() is "a function that takes unknown amount of arguments." These arguments are of an unspecified type.

Foo(void) is used across both languages with the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Both are equivalent, so this is merely a choice of style. I prefer `Foo()` because it involves less typing and it's what I've seen more often.

This question has actually been [covered before on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032/is-there-a-difference-between-foovoid-and-foo-in-c-or-c).

Apparently `foo()` in C means "a function `foo` taking an unspecified number of arguments of unspecified type" where in C++ it means "a function `foo` taking no arguments."

Comment: I also used that as you can see more easily whether the constructor takes arguments or not. I was just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Only when the constructor and destructor do not need any arguments, there are the same. Also `Foo(void)` seems less frequently used.