# void parameter in functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

The Visual C++ "Add class" wizard creates code where constructors and destructors contain the `void` keyword in the parameter list.

For example:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass(void);
  ~MyClass(void); 
};
```

instead of:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass();
  ~MyClass(); 
};
```

Is this a microsoftism  is it actually the correct way to do in c++?

Comment: [Is there a difference between foo(void) and foo() in C++ or C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/51032/3953764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Microsoftism, as a stylistic holdover from C (in which it does have a distinct meaning)

I've seen a few people use this style in C++ code, but very rarely from anything but ignorance. In my experience, the rest have switched over when informed.

Of course, [in C++, there's no functional difference whatsoever](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51032/560648).