# C's Undefined Behaviour

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int *fun();
int main()
{
    int *t;
    t=fun();
    printf("%d\n",*t);
    printf("%d\n",*t);
}
int *fun()
{
    int r=95;
    return(&r);
}
```

The output shown by this code in codeblocks is

```
95
-2
```

I don't get why the second `printf()` is printing a garbage value. Can someone explain that, please?

Comment: Use prototype declarators! And enable compiler warnings.

Comment: By editing `int fun()` --> `int *fun()` after answers have pointed that deficiency out, negates that value of the answers.  Better to 1) revert the edit. 2) if needed, append a note,  acknowledging that issue and need for continued help.

Comment: Please tell us what warning/s you got when you compiled this.

Answer (score 1):

This is UB, because `r` is a local variable inside `fun()`, and if you return the address of a local variable and try to use it in the caller, you're ending up using it after is has expired it's lifetime. In `C`, it is defined as UB.

FWIW, the address of a variable is **not always** equivalent to an `int` or can be converted to a pointer safely, thus it should be `int *`, at least. In your code,

```
t=fun();
```

and

```
return(&r);
```

should have given you warnings!!

Comment: Also, returning a pointer as `int` is bad.

Comment: @MikeCAT yes, right.

Comment: It actually shall be. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p6 . Only two safe integers to take a pointer are `(u)intptr_t`.

Comment: @Olaf added some clarifications to that. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You return an `int*` from `fun`, even though it's declared to return `int`. Change the declaration to `int* fun()`.
2. [An empty list allows a variable number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032/is-there-a-difference-between-foovoid-and-foo-in-c-or-c). Use `int* fun(void);` instead.
3. Undefined behavior is undefined behavior. You try to [access memory of a local variable from outside the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable), so **anything might happen**. From the level of the C standard, it's plainly **undefined** whether the first, second, or no statement at all behaves weirdly (like "printing a garbage value").