# The 'for' not running well

Tags: c++, for-loop, average

When I'm trying to run the program and execute it the for loop doesn't repeat of an adequate form, when I'm trying to execute it appears me this:

```
Enter a number:
5.6
Enter a number:
Enter a number:
Enter a number:
Enter a number:
Enter a number:
Enter a number:
Enter a number:
Enter a number:
Enter a number:
```

I tried to search some information about this problem, but I don't found anything. I know that is a foolish question but I don't know where else to turn. A help is appreciated.
I left you my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (void){
    int num, sum;
    float average;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        cout << " Enter a number: " <<endl;
        cin >>i;
        sum += num;
    }   
        average = num / 10;
        cout << " The total average is:\n " << media <<endl; 
}
```

Comment: You don't check if `cin >>i;` actually succeeds.

Comment: You are not initializing `sum` or `num` before use, causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: Also, you meant `cin >> num;` rather than `cin >> i;`

Comment: In addition to the previous comments, you probably also meant `average = sum / 10;`

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt for example *int num =0;*  *int sum =0;*

Comment: By the way, are you sure this compiles? It doesn't on my machine, because `media`.

Comment: And even if you correct all the errors, are you sure a float average of 10 integers makes sense? You'd end up with 2.4 children.

Comment: @MrLister what's exactly wrong with having 2.4 children in the average family? It's a good healthy number.

Comment: why do you read into the for loop variable?

Comment: @ Lưu Vĩnh Phúc for repeat in order to introduce a more number  until to arrive to one that will not comply the condition.

Answer (score 0):

`cin` fails its formatted input operation. It was expecting an integer, but you entered into it a floating point number. Hence, it failed. change the input to a `float` or `double`.

A couple of more problems with your code:

- You can write `int main()`, rather `int main(void)`. The `void` isn't quite useful here
- Always initialize your variables before use
- Sometimes, check for `cin` failures and report errors if need be

Corrected code...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    int num = 0, sum = 0;
    float average = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        cout << " Enter a number: " <<endl;
        if(!(cin >> num)){   //you can also use a while loop to force requirement of proper input
             cin.clear();
             cin.ignore(100000, '\n');
             // you can print an error message here
        }
        else
             sum += num;
    }   
        average = static_cast<float>(sum) / 10;
        cout << " The total average is:\n " << average <<endl; 
}
```

See [Why would we call cin.clear() and cin.ignore() after reading input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input)

Comment: @WhiZTiM !cin >> num, what does this do? doesn't ! have a higher precedence than >>?

Comment: Cast `sum` to `float` before using division: `average = (float)sum / 10;`

Comment: @juanchopanza, true... but that syntax was inherited in compatibility with `C` which meant a function with no argument because in C, `int main()` really means a function with a variable number of argument.... That doesn't hold for C++. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032/is-there-a-difference-between-foovoid-and-foo-in-c-or-c

Comment: So what? You were suggesting something is wrong with that. In a post with so many genuine bugs, it seems confusing to talk about something that is fine as if it wasn't.

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaHuỳnh, Thanks ^^ Corrected... |{|}| Thanks bkVnet, clarified

Comment: @juanchopanza, ... Well, you are right, but don't you think its good to point people to "more modern" ways? ... Nonetheless, I have corrected my use of strong "Don't use"

Answer (score 0):

You have three things that ain't correct:

- First of all, you have to initialize **sum** before using, like so **int sum = 0;**.
- Second of all, the entered number has to be saved in a variable. You can't use **i** as that variable 'cause it's you loop iterator, therefore you can use **num**.
- Last of all, **media** has no meaning in your program. and i know you meant to use **average**.

After correcting all of these, your program should look like this one:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (void){
    int num, sum=0;
    float average;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        cout << " Enter a number: ";
        cin >>num;
        sum += num;
    }   
    average = num / 10;
    cout << " The total average is:\n " << average <<endl; 
    system("pause");
}
```