# How to migrate C function pointers to C++?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, function-pointers

The following is using a function pointer in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void bar1(int i){printf("bar1 %d\n", i+1);}
void bar2(int i){printf("bar2 %d\n", i+2);}
void foo(void (*func)(), int i) {func(i);};
int main() {
    foo(bar2, 0);
}
```

It compiles with `$gcc main.c`.

The following is my attempt to migrate it to C++:

```
#include <cstdio>
void bar1(int i){printf("bar1 %d\n", i+1);}
void bar2(int i){printf("bar2 %d\n", i+2);}
void foo(void (*func)(), int i) {func(i);};
int main() {
    foo(bar2, 0);
}
```

Trying to compile it, I get errors:

```
$ g++ main.cpp
main.cpp:7:39: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 1
void foo(void (*func)(), int i) {func(i);};
                                 ~~~~ ^
main.cpp:10:2: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
        foo(bar2, 0);
        ^~~
main.cpp:7:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'void (int)' to 'void (*)()' for 1st argument
void foo(void (*func)(), int i) {func(i);};
     ^
2 errors generated.
```

How can I migrate C function pointers to C++?

Comment: You declare the argument to foo to be a pointer to function that doesn't take arguments. Fix that.

Comment: You mean it should be `void (*func)(int i)`, even in `C`? May I ask why `C` compiler don't ask me that?

Comment: Probably related/possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032/is-there-a-difference-between-foovoid-and-foo-in-c-or-c

Comment: It is because in C function can not be overloaded. You may still want to compile with something like `-fstrict-prototypes` to ensure that function signature remains consistent everywhere.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C, `void f()` declares `f` to be function that takes an unspecified number of arguments and returns `int`. In C++ it declares `f` to be a function that takes no arguments and returns `int`. In C, if you want to write a function that takes no arguments you use `void` as the argument list: `void f(void)` declares a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing.

Unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, the way to write the code in the question is `void foo(void (*func)(int), int i)`. That says that `func` is a pointer to a function that takes one argument of type `int` and returns `void`.

Comment: Just for comparison: C's equivalent of the C++ function pointer: `void (*func)(` **void** `)` (for functions analogously, require explicit void parameter).

Comment: @Aconcagua -- good point. I've edited my answer to mention `void` as an argument list in C.