# shared library error about "undefined symbol" when using `dlopen`

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

First thing first, here's my minimum reproducible program:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(untitled4)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_library(lib1 SHARED lib1.cpp)

add_executable(untitled4 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(untitled4 PRIVATE dl)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "iostream"
#include <dlfcn.h>
int Test() {
  return 123456;
}
int main() {
  auto* handler = dlopen("/home/liu/source/untitled4/cmake-build-debug/liblib1.so", RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_GLOBAL);
  if (!handler) {
    std::cerr << dlerror();
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

and lib1.cpp:

```
#include "iostream"
extern int Test();
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo() {
    std::cout << Test() << std::endl;
  }
};
Foo foo;
```

now let me explain:

As you can see I defined a function called `Test` in main.cpp, and I want to the shared library `liblib1.so` call it when it is loaded.

But when I run the `main()` function, there's an error log said:

```
/home/liu/source/untitled4/cmake-build-debug/liblib1.so: undefined symbol: _Z4Testv
```

I check the symbol by using `nm untitled4 |grep Test` and the symbol seems exist:

```
0000000000000b87 t _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z4Testv
0000000000000aea T _Z4Testv
```

So what did I do wrong? How to fix this?

An important thing to be notice is that in the real case, the build of `lib1` and the build of `main.cpp` are totally separated, the two build don't know each other. But I can make them into one build (very difficult) if this can fix the problem(if there's no other way).

P.S. I tried using extern "C" to wrap around the `Test()` in both files, but not working, seems not the C/C++ function naming problem.

Comment: I wonder how `lib1` library is successfully built when it uses `Test` function but doesn't link with definition if this function. Have you somehow suppressed "undefined reference" error when **build** the library? Note, that CMake has a special kind of library intended for `dlopen` usage: `MODULE` (instead of `SHARED`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev sounds reasonable, I will investigate

Comment: @Tsyvarev With the info I got from you I made a small example and it works without problems (no warnings either with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors`), but I'm building it manually,

Comment: Error "undefined reference" is a **linker** error. It has nothing common with `-Wall` and other options you have specified, because these options are for **compiler**. Not sure what do you mean by "I'm building it manually". Do you mean "without CMake"? Or what?

Comment: Note, that declaring a function with **empty** argument list - `int Test()` - is a legacy (**old way**). While in C++ it is synonym for  `int Test(void)`, in C their meaning is different. It is better to always specify `void` instead of empty argument list: `int Test(void)`. See that question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032/is-there-a-difference-between-foovoid-and-foo-in-c-or-c.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, I built it using `g++` commands from the command line. I didn't mean that the `-Warnings` was for the linker. I just meant that the code was compiled without warnings. Linking was done with `g++ -rdynamic -o main main.o -ldl`. No suppression.

Comment: In the my first comment I told about creation/linking of the **library** (`lib1.cpp`), not the **executable** (`main.cpp`). The executable is obviously could be built successfully: it is not linked with the library and doesn't use its symbols directly.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry, that I built with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors -fPIC -c -o lib1.o lib1.cpp` and `g++ -shared -o liblib1.so lib1.o`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think the answer is that OP misses `-rdynamic` while linking the final executable. I get the same error if I exclude that flag.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Oops, sorry, I confused your comments with the asker ones. Yes, the C++ code itself looks correct. CMake project should (from my understanding) also work with `SHARED` replaced by `MODULE`. As for `-rdynamic`, it should be added by CMake automatically.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Re: `-rdynamic` Yeah, it doesn't look like a flag that one should need to add explicitly. Perhaps using `MODULE` instead as you say is the solution. One thing that _does_ look like a potential problem is the global `Foo foo;`. It looks like [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof) waiting to happen, but that's a "future" problem. Not the one OP asks about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225107/discussion-between-ted-lyngmo-and-tsyvarev).

Comment: I tested with `-rdynamic` and it works, as to use `MODULE`, unfortunately it will not work without `-rdynamic`, neither does `SHARED`, which I will do a further investigate to figure out why, as to the Order Fiasco, my real case use lazy initialization, won't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the addition of the linker option [`-rdynamic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) your code does not fail with "*undefined symbol*".

You can set that with `set_target_properties(untitled4 PROPERTIES ENABLE_EXPORTS 1)` or `target_link_options(untitled4 BEFORE PRIVATE "-rdynamic")`.

Example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(untitled4)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_library(lib1 SHARED lib1.cpp)

add_executable(untitled4 main.cpp)
set_target_properties(untitled4 PROPERTIES ENABLE_EXPORTS 1)

target_link_libraries(untitled4 PRIVATE dl)
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo: It is normal for a library, which is loaded by an application via `dlopen`, to have access to all functions, defined in that application. Linkage to that functions is performed by `dlopen` itself, no manual intervention is needed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I added a `CMake` workaround instead. Perhaps it can be made in a better way, but I'm a `CMake` newbie.

Comment: I searched that the "CMake" style of doing this is `set_target_properties(untitled4 PROPERTIES ENABLE_EXPORTS 1)`, probably better than use compiler flags, which is more portable.

Comment: @psionic12 Nice! I updated it with that alternative.